# How to Install libflashplayer.so?

Tags: 10.04, firefox, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

I cannot figure out how to install Adobe Flashplayer plugin in Firefox 3.6.3. I downloaded libflashplayer.so, have read a few forums for ways to install but nothing so far has worked. One of the ways I've tried is to copy the .so file to the firefox plugin folder but my system does not allow me to copy anything into that folder.
Thanks,

-h.