# How can I install Adobe Flash player?

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I view flash video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-view-flash-video)

I'm trying to install flash player on my new install of Ubuntu 10.10. I've tried several ways, from the flash player website, another question on here, and I asked a friend of mine for help, but none of them seem to be working.

I'm pretty illiterate with Ubuntu (this is my 1st time using it), therefore I would politely ask for a explanation with all steps required.

Thank you in advance for your help.