# Firefox with Ubufox does not find plugins

Tags: 11.04, firefox, plugins

When I try to open a flash site or Java applet, Firefox tells me that there are some missing plugins available.

But once i click on that button of the top bar, Firefox doesn't find anything. Only manual install is then available.

I remember that in previous versions of Ubuntu, Firefox recognized automatically all plugins and installed them trough apt etc...

Is this a bug? Only me with this problem here? Because for new users this is an important feature!

ps. the Ubufox extension is still installed

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether previous versions of Ubuntu installed Flash automatically, but I doubt it. In any case, there's this answer: [How can I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33128/how-can-i-install-adobe-flash-player) You can also use Software Center instead of Synaptic.

For the Java plugin, search for "Java plugin" in Software Center or Synaptic, and you will find the [Icedtea Java Plugin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/icedtea-plugin).