# How to enable flash for Google Chrome 13?

Tags: 11.04, 64-bit, flash, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the Flash in Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2544/where-is-the-flash-in-chrome)
>   [How can I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33128/how-can-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty and I wanna use Google Chrome, but in about:plugin there are only 3 plugins: Chrome NaCl (Disabled), Chrome PDF Viewer and Default Plug-in - Version: 1. How do I install flash for this version of Chrome on 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: I linked you to the wrong instructions the first time, here you go: http://askubuntu.com/questions/2544/where-is-the-flash-in-chrome