# Flash player for 11.04 64bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11/how-do-i-install-adobe-flash-player)

How do install adobe flash player for my 64 bit 11.04? Also is it stable yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously, Flash for 64-bit machines was in testing and provided by the `sevenmachines/flash` PPA (see also 
[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)). If you've previously installed this PPA, remove the packages `flashplugin64-installer` and ``flashplugin64-nonfree and the PPA file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/sevenmachines-flash-*.list` (`*` = distro version). [Terminal commands](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969):

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin64-installer flashplugin64-nonfree
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sevenmachines-flash-*.list
```

Then, continue installing the flash plugin as described at [How do I install Adobe Flash player?](https://askubuntu.com/q/11/6969)

Comment: Update: The package name is actually flashplugin64-installer (not *-nonfree).

Comment: And what about fullscreen FullHD (1920x1050) video in youtube? Doesn't lag?

Comment: @ Extender - I have no idea about that because I use the 32 bit version. :)

Comment: @ monotasker - I visited this page > https://launchpad.net/~sevenmachines/+archive/flash and there, the package name was *flashplugin64-nonfree*. :)

Comment: Who is this `sevenmachines` in charge of the PPA? An Adobe employee?

Comment: @Oxwivi I don't think so.

Comment: Then how is he creating the packages? He'd need the source code, which I believe to be attainable only as an Adobe employee.

Comment: @Oxwivi It's only an installer - which is open source. All it does is download the binary, closed source libflashplayer.so directly from Adobe and stuffs it in the right place (along with some other gumph - see synaptic for more detail on exactly what the package provides)

Comment: @Oli, thanks for the info. So it's basically does the same thing as `flashplugin-installer`, but pulls the binary from Adobe instead Canonical repository, right?

Comment: @Oxwivi AFAIK, the standard `flashplugin-installer` package pulls from Adobe too. I haven't tested but I can't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: @Oli, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49298/whats-the-difference-between-flashplugin-installer-and-adobe-flashplugin/49312#49312).

Comment: sevenmachines PPA has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Flash was never completly stable to be honest.

You can install flash player by searching "adobe flash plugin" in Ubuntu software center.