# What is a terminal and how do I open and use it?

Tags: command-line

- What is a terminal?
- How do I open a terminal window?
- How do I use the terminal?

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?](//askubuntu.com/q/506510/309110)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

### What is it:

The terminal is an interface in which you can type and execute text based commands.

[image: terminal screenshot]

---

### Why use it:

It can be much faster to complete some tasks using a Terminal than with graphical applications and menus. Another benefit is allowing access to many more commands and scripts.

A common terminal task of installing an application can be achieved within a single command, compared to navigating through the Software Centre or Synaptic Manager.

For example the following would install Deluge bittorrent client:

```
sudo apt-get install deluge
```

To save a detailed list of files in the current directory tree to a file called `listing.txt`:

```
find -type f > listing.txt
```

Sometimes you will also see the following notation:

```
$ whoami
calum
$ ls
Downloads  Documents
```

This means that the command `whoami` is executed which gives `calum` as output. Following that command, `ls` is executed which outputs `Downloads  Documents`.

A similar notation is:

```
# apt-get update
```

This means that the command should be run as root, that is, using `sudo`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Note that the `#` character is also used for *comments*.

```
# this command will give your username
whoami
# the next command will show the contents of the current directory
ls
```

---

### How do I open a terminal:

- Open the **Dash** (Super Key) or
  **Applications** and type `terminal`

  [image]
- Use the keyboard shortcut by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
- For older or Ubuntu versions: [*(More Info)*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting%20a%20Terminal)

  Applications → Accessories → Terminal

---

### Alternative names for the terminal:

- Console
- Shell
- Command line
- Command prompt

(Although technically [they mean different things](https://askubuntu.com/q/506510/301745))

---

### Common commands & Further information

- Ubuntu Documentation: [Using The
  Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

Comment: Another reason that people helping you will prefer to give you terminal-based commands over directing you through a GUI is simply because you type everything in directly. There's no searching for applications and/or menu items. Don't be put off by the sole text-interface. To this day, whenever I open a command-prompt in Windows, people instantly ask me if I'm hacking their computer or some other such nonsense. The terminal is your friend.

Comment: Another advantage is that everything you do in the terminal can be scripted and automated.

Comment: **Lazy tip:** You can use [drag and drop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_and_drop) to drop files and folders from the filemanager into the terminal, which will give you the complete path to apply a command to the file. It's the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 6):

A Terminal is your interface to the underlying operating system via a shell, usually bash. It is a command line.

Back in the day, a Terminal was a screen+keyboard that was connected to a server. Today, it is usally just a progam.

You can open it via the utilities part of the apllications menu, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-terminal`.

Answer (score 4):

The terminal (also known as console) is an application in which you can execute commands directly. It looks like:

[image: gnome-terminal screenshot]

You can start the terminal from Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal.
If you're not using Gnome, but KDE (Kubuntu), you would find it under: Kickoff menu -> Applications -> System -> Konsole.

The Ubuntu wiki has [an article about the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) which includes information on starting the terminal in Xubuntu and Lubuntu, and a basic overview of commonly used commands. It's recommended for reading as it includes much examples as well.

Comment: "Shell" and "terminal" don't really mean the same thing. For example, in the screenshot above, the terminal is probably `gnome-terminal`. The shell is probably `bash`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, those are indeed not the same. However, I mentioned it because the word "shell" is often used to refer to the place where you can enter commands. It happens to be that the terminal opens that shell, but a novice user may not directly relate it.

Answer (score 1):

> A Terminal is a command interpreter. A Terminal is an entity that takes input from the user and deals with the computer rather than the user deal directly with the computer. If the user had to deal directly with the computer he would not get much done as the computer only understands strings of 1's and 0's

**Example**

When a person drives a car, that person doesn't have to actually adjust every detail that goes along with making the engine run, or the electronic system controlling all of the engine timing and so on. The dashboard would also be considered part of the the Terminal since pertinent (Having logical precise relevance to the matter at hand) information relating to the user's involvement in operating the car is displayed there. In fact any part of the car that the user has control of during operation of the car would be considered part of the Terminal.

Terminal is a program that allows the user to use the computer without him having to deal directly with it. It is in a sense a protective shell that prevents the user and computer from coming into contact with one another.

[How Do I Use It ? @ cas](https://askubuntu.com/users/8570/cas?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=1)

Answer (score -1):

Simply said, a **Terminal** is a CLI (Command Line Interface) to interact with programs in the computer.

In Ubuntu you can open a terminal:

- by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

or

- by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, type "terminal" and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can use the terminal for various tasks, such as:

- Installing, updating, and deleting software.
- For power off, reboot, sleep...
- Creating and removing files and folders.
- [Many more...](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)