# Reading logs after I've had to hard reboot

Tags: 10.10, freeze, suspend, reboot, log

I have a VGA to S-Video converter which I use to watch movies on the TV from my laptop, but after I've plugged it the laptop starts freezing whenever I try to suspend it or hibernate it. Can I read some log files to see what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logfiles are located in `/var/log`.

- Log files related to suspend:

  ```
  /var/log/pm-suspend.log
  ```

  - Older entries (# is a number):

    ```
    /var/log/pm-suspend.log.#
    /var/log/pm-suspend.log.#.gz
    ```

    The latter one with the `.gz` prefix is a compressed file and must be uncompressed before reading.
- Related to the X server (0 is the display number, it's usually 0 unless you switch users):

  ```
  /var/log/Xorg.0.log
  /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log
  ```

  - Older entries:

    ```
    /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
    /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log.old
    ```

Useful commands for [the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969):

- Reads the log file and present it in a pager. You can use arrow keys, Page up/Down and Home/End to navigate. Compressed files are recognized too, there is no need to uncompress them before use:

  ```
  less /var/log/pm-suspend.log
  ```
- Uncompressed a file and saves it to `file`. The latter program (`gunzip`) removes the original `file.gz` file

  ```
  zcat file.gz > file
  gunzip file.gz
  ```
- Monitor logs (add new lines as they are added):

  ```
  tail -f /var/log/kern.log
  ```
- List log files, sorted by last modification date:

  ```
  ls -lAtr /var/log
  ```