# Ubuntu-Kubuntu start-up messed up: how to clean up?

Tags: 11.04, package-management, kubuntu, session

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 recently. Then for the sake of trying, i installed the Kubuntu Plasma package from the Software Repos. I didn't like Kubuntu, so i removed the same package from the Software Centre again.

Some programs remain from the Kubuntu Session however: like K-torrent which came to replace Transmission as a default torrent program. Then the splash screen remains that of Kubuntu and not Ubuntu and finally the session randomly logs out!!

I'm quite shocked, i thought that by now Ubuntu could handle this kind of switches easily and cleanly.

But first things first, how do i clean this mess up?

Several Kunbuntu packages are still on my computer if i believe Synaptic. I didn't dare taking them out without knowing what i do.

Please help.
B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package, uninstalling it will not remove its dependencies. Look in your `/var/log/apt/history.log` for the packages installed with `kubuntu-desktop`.

It's format is like:

```
Start-Date: [date and time of installation]
Commandline: apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
Install: package1:arch (version), package2:arch (version)
End-Date: [date and time when finished]
```

The next command will display the command for removing all packages which where installed with `kubuntu-desktop` (run it in a [terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969)):

```
grep '^Install: .* kubuntu-desktop' /var/log/apt/history.log | head -n1 | sed -E 's/:(amd64|i386) \([^)]+\),?//g;s/Install:/sudo apt-get purge/'
```

If you're not sure whether it's the right one, paste it on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and comment on this answer.

Comment: Thanks. The command line doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: I'm not good with Perl, so i did the regex manually with LibreOffice. You may want to check your code, cause it didn't do much on my side. For the rest it worked great! thanks.

Comment: I missed a `'` at the end of the line. The RE is OK, I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

The kind person at [Psychocats](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/puregnome) have compiled a complete list of all KDE pacakges.  As you are using Natty, try the following in the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-server akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils appmenu-qt apport-kde apturl-kde ark bluedevil cdparanoia cdrdao docbook-xsl dolphin dragonplayer freespacenotifier gdebi-core gdebi-kde gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm gtk2-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 icoutils jockey-kde k3b k3b-data kaddressbook kamera kate kcalc kde-config-gtk kde-config-touchpad kde-window-manager kde-zeroconf kdebase-bin kdebase-data kdebase-runtime kdebase-runtime-data kdebase-workspace kdebase-workspace-bin kdebase-workspace-data kdebase-workspace-kgreet-plugins kdegames-card-data kdegraphics-libs-data kdegraphics-strigi-plugins kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-groupware kdepim-kresources kdepim-runtime kdepim-strigi-plugins kdepim-wizards kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdesudo kdm kdoctools kfind khelpcenter4 kinfocenter klipper kmag kmail kmix kmousetool knm-runtime knotes konsole kontact kopete kopete-message-indicator korganizer kpackagekit kpat kppp krdc krfb krosspython ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktimetracker ktorrent ktorrent-data kubuntu-debug-installer kubuntu-default-settings kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-docs kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-konqueror-shortcuts kubuntu-netbook-default-settings kubuntu-notification-helper kvkbd kwalletmanager language-selector-kde libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kabc4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libao-common libao4 libasyncns0 libattica0 libaudio2 libbluedevil1 libboost-program-options1.42.0 libcln6 libclucene0ldbl libdbusmenu-qt2 libdebconf-kde0 libdiscid0 libdmtx0a libepub0 libflac++6 libgif4 libgpgme++2 libgps19 libibus-qt1 libilmbase6 libindicate-qt1 libiodbc2 libk3b6 libkabc4 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcddb4 libkcmutils4 libkdcraw9 libkde3support4 libkdecorations4 libkdecore5 libkdegames5 libkdepim4 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4a libkexiv2-9 libkfile4 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkimap4 libkimproxy4 libkio5 libkipi8 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkleo4 libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4 libkonq5-templates libkonq5a libkontactinterface4 libkopete4 libkparts4 libkpgp4 libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libksba8 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent2 libkunitconversion4 libkutils4 libkwineffects1a libkworkspace4 libkxmlrpcclient4 liblastfm0 libloudmouth1-0 libmailtransport4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmicroblog4 libmimelib4 libmng1 libmpcdec6 libmsn0.3 libmusicbrainz3-6 libmysqlclient16 libnepomuk4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libntrack-qt4-1 libntrack0 libokularcore1 libopenexr6 libotr2 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpackagekit-qt14 libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4b libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-3 libpowerdevilcore0 libprocesscore4b libprocessui4a libqalculate5 libqapt-runtime libqapt1 libqca2 libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtwebkit4 libreadline5 libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen libsolid4 libsolidcontrol4a libsolidcontrolifaces4a libsoprano4 libssh-4 libstreamanalyzer0 libstreams0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4b libthreadweaver4 libvirtodbc0 libvncserver0 libweather-ion6 libzip1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.1 nepomukcontroller network-manager-pptp-kde ntrack-module-libnl-0 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme oxygen-icon-theme oxygen-icon-theme-complete packagekit packagekit-backend-aptcc partitionmanager phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-declarative plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-kimpanel-backend-ibus plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-message-indicator plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widget-quickaccess plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text polkit-kde-1 printer-applet python-kde4 python-packagekit python-pyudev python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python-sip qapt-batch quassel quassel-data rekonq shared-desktop-ontologies software-properties-kde soprano-daemon system-config-printer-kde systemsettings update-manager-kde usb-creator-kde userconfig virtuoso-minimal virtuoso-opensource-6.1-bin virtuoso-opensource-6.1-common && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Copy and paste this into a terminal to remove all KDE packages from your system.

Comment: Yep. Got that one from ubuntuforums.org as well. The thing is packages may change over time, and picking up the log file's content is more reliable. Thanks though :)