# How to best copy large files to an SD card?

Tags: files, clipboard, sd-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying files to SD card not saving](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43525/copying-files-to-sd-card-not-saving)

When copying large (or even files of a few KB) to an SD card from [Ubuntu 10.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_10.10_.28Maverick_Meerkat.29) (Maverick Meerkat), the files appear to be there, but when I access the card from another device, the files are either missing or 0 bytes in size.

I suspect that the problem is that it takes time for the files to copy to the card and I'm taking it out too soon, but there is no progress bar - I'm just doing it from the command line. And it even happens when I cleanly eject the card.

Is there a preferred way to do this so I can know that the files are copied?

Comment: `cp` won't return the prompt until it has finished copying, so I don't think that is your issue, unless you are CTRL-C'ing the `cp` command. I don't have a solution, I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: rest assured that i was not killing the copy, then asking why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using "safely remove device" button before removing the card from the card reader - to speed up things, the OS buffers data in memory, so the copying process may finish early but the actual data may not be yet written to the card.

To do this, you need to click on the Eject icon next to your card's entry in the left pane of the file browser, and *wait until the icon disappears*, indicating that the card is unmounted. From my experience, this actually may take longer than the original copy operation took because the cards are quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

gcp: Command-line Based File Copy Tool for Ubuntu Linux with progress bar

http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/03/gcp-command-line-file-copy-ubuntu-linux/

or try the "bar" or the "pv"commands with progress bar

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/bar.1.html

does the same error appear with nautilus?

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1963239