# Unrar fails when accents are present in filenames

Tags: archive, compression

I have the `rar` package installed. Double clicking on `.rar` files opens the file in Archive manager. It works fine when folders or files use only characters with no accentuation, but if there is some accentuation present (**inside** the archives, not on the archive container filenames), then files that will open just fine in Windows using Winrar, 7zip or other archiver will produce an error message in Ubuntu.

The Archive Manager window will show the file list with wrong charsets, and trying to extract the files will produce two distinct errors:

If I double click the file:

```
RAR 4.00 beta 3   Copyright (c) 1993-2010 Alexander Roshal   17 Dec 2010
Shareware version         Type RAR -? for help


Extracting from /media/folder/file.rar

No files to extract
```

If I use the extract command:

all the files in the archive will be extracted but `(invalid encoding)` will be attached to the end of the folders and files with accentuation.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/220240/how-to-make-archive-manager-recognize-cyrillic-chracters

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48130/encoding-and-decoding-error-in-non-english-name-of-compressed-file

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First install unrar using below command:

`sudo apt install unrar`

then running

`unrar x /path/to/file`

will decompress the files with no encoding errors.

Apparently the issue is caused by the Archive Manager. (I'd really like to be able to use Archive Manager and the GUI, so if someone has a better answer I'll gladly accept it!)

Comment: when there's no GUI for a good command like that what i do is try add it to context menu actions (i use Thunar custom actions but Nautilus has that feature of course). to do that the command has to adapted in some cases

Comment: fresh comment on an old post : as of today, engrampa works fine with rar files.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with a `.rar` file that contained non-standard Unicode symbols in the filenames. Solved it like this:

```
sudo apt install rar
rar e filename.rar
```

Answer (score 2):

Here these commands work fine and solved my problem.

first, install unrar on Ubuntu using the below commands.

```
sudo apt install unrar-free
sudo apt install unrar
```

Now extract your rar files using below commands

```
unrar x /path-where-rar-file-exist  /path-you-want-to-extract
unrar x p1.rar /var/www/html/
```