# Is there some kind of icon browser?

Tags: software-recommendation, icons, browser

When making a custom launcher, it is nice to have a matching icon for it from the default usr ubuntu directories. The problem that is: Ubuntu seems to store icons in about 50 or more folders. Browsing all of them in nautilus takes ages.

So my question is:
Is there some kind of icon browser that shows an overview of all icons in /usr/share/icons/*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of opening the folders one by one, you can also use the Search feature of Nautilus. Navigate to `/usr/share/icons`, and press the Search icon on the right of the toolbar.

Search for `.` (all images have an extension with a dot before it) and press Enter. On a default installation, this yields about 17.5k images. That's not much of an "overview", but it includes all files in `/usr/share/icons`.

If you wish to avoid searching each time, you could make use of symbolic links to the images: all images are accessible from one big folder.

1. [Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal)
2. To check the number of files that can be created after creating the links:

   ```
   expr $(df /home -i | tail -1 | cut -d'%' -f1 | rev | awk '{ print $2 }' | rev) - $(find /usr/share/icons -type f | wc -l)
   ```

   You should not continue if the number is lower than 1000 and a negative number will cause the operation to fail after some time.
3. Make an folder named `icons-all` by running: `mkdir icons-all`
4. Go into that folder: `cd icons-all`
5. Run `nano /tmp/make-icons-link`
6. Paste:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if [[ $1 == *.* ]]; then
           ext=".${1##*.}"
   else
           ext=
   fi
   name="$(basename "$1" "$ext")"
   extra=
   while [ -e "$name$extra$ext" ]; do
       ((extra++))
   done
   ln -s "$1" "$name$extra$ext"
   ```
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
8. Now generate the links, this may take a while:

   ```
   find /usr/share/icons/ -type f -exec bash /tmp/make-icons-link {} \;
   ```

   After the command has completed, no output is shown.
9. Close the terminal by running `exit`
10. The images are now visible in `~/icons-all`. Loading this directory may take a while

Comment: I had the same problem I found the solution above very slow - so I used picassa to index - I found this to be effective.

Comment: @user52652 will picasa try to index all photos on my HD like shotwell seems to be doing b4 I can see anything? I just gaveup on shotwell btw..

Comment: Using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS copy and paste command in **Step 2.** returns: 2309035.

Comment: Thanks for this script which was very useful. By default it created too large of a collection. But if you just pick a select number of key folder/sizes, it works very well...

find  /usr/share/icons/breeze/apps/48/ -type f -exec bash /tmp/make-icons-link {} \;
find  /usr/share/icons/breeze/status/64/ -type f -exec bash /tmp/make-icons-link {} \;

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [the answer by @Lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/a/48731), I found that the file manager PCManFM-Qt (executable `pcmanfm-qt`) can be used in a similar fashion. It is the default file manager installed under LXQt, but can also be installed in any Ubuntu installation with `sudo apt install pcmanfm-qt`.

1. Go to an icon (sub-)folder of interest, such as `/usr/share/icons/breeze`.
2. Set "View → View → Icon view" for a folder view with icon thumbnails.
3. Open the "Tools → Find Files…" dialog and search using the following parameters:

   - File Name Patterns: `*`
   - Use regular expression: checked
   - Search in sub directories: checked
   - File Type → Image files: checked

When clicking next to the <kbd>Search</kbd> button above the result list, you will see that the file manager uses a search URL internally to represent this search, such as:

```
search:///usr/share/icons/breeze?recursive=1&name_regex=*&mime_types=image/*
```

You can copy&paste this for future use to get back to these search results faster, and you can also start the file manager to show these search results immediately:

```
pcmanfm-qt "search:///usr/share/icons/breeze?recursive=1&name_regex=*&mime_types=image/*"
```