# How can I change the percent of screen brightness that changes every time I press the shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness

When I press Fn+F6 the change in brightness is too big. How can I make it move less than it does now? (Let's say, half that, for example.)

(11.04/Gnome. I'm on proprietary nvidia drivers.)

EDIT: I haven't tried what Rinzwind has written below because , after throwing a cup of coffee on my laptop, my keyboard was destroyed (so i no longer have the FN button that is needed - i'm currently writing from an external one). I have already ordered a new one and i will collect it from the service center tomorrow at noon

Comment: What is the brand of you system? Dell???

Comment: Chriskin notes below that this is a Fujitsu.

Comment: have you gotten around to trying Rinzwind's fix yet?

Comment: yes, i have already given an answer below. short story is , if you are bored to read it : it didn't work :S

Answer (score 3):

[From bug 207473](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal/+bug/207473/comments/6) "Screen brightness double level changes on Dell laptops".

- If your problem is an error in hal or acpid you can circumvent it by adding `blacklist video` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist`.
- Testing can be done by issuing:

  ```
  /etc/init.d/acpid stop
  /etc/init.d/hal stop
  ```

  If this works 2 programs are changing the brightness level at the same time (thus doubling it) and you should add yourself to the affected people on the bug too (it's old and never got fixed it seems?).

Comment: should i try it even though my system is not made by Dell? I use a  fujitsu lifebook nh570.

Comment: sure! you can always go back by removing the line from the blacklist file. acpid and hal with 'start' starts them up again. Not a lot can go wrong!

Comment: thanks , I'll try it tomorrow because, as i wrote above, i destroyed my laptop's keyboard.

Comment: @Rinzwind, the linked bug says the problem is for Dell laptops. Maybe it would be better if he just filed a separate bug report?

Comment: It's always better to file 1 more bug than not :) If you do... try using brightness with acpi and hal stopped and post the results on it in the bug.

Comment: Just tried the solution above and I have to say that it didn't work - it just made it impossible to change the brightness at all (until i remove the line from the blacklist file and restarted, i mean). I don't have enough time these days to take care of a bug report (answering questions, sending terminal outputs etc) because i spend too little time online. I will report it , though, in about a week that my university exams will end. I'd rather not make a bug report that i would answer to every other day, it would be really annoying to those who would try to help

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Was worth a shot though :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, you can confirm it yourself.

[Open a terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) and run:

```
cd /sys/class/backlight/*
```

To get the current brightness level:

```
cat brightness
```

To display the maximum brightness, run:

```
cat max_brightness
```

The brightness level can be a value between 0 and the output of `max_brightness`. To change it to 5, run:

```
echo 5 | sudo tee brightness
```

Using these commands, you can confirm that brightness cannot be changes in "percents", just in "levels".

Comment: Having tested what you said i found that , when i change my brightness level, it always changes by two. Meaning that the only way to go to brightness level 1 (that i use a lot lately) i have to go to max and then go back from there (11-9-7-5-3-1)

Is it supposed to move by two every time? If it is, is there any way to make it move by one?

Answer (score 1):

Using the commands provided on [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107046/349837), on Gnome Shell (17.10 and above) go to **Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Custom shortcuts**, clic on the plus button:

[image]