# How to increase brightness in smaller steps?

Tags: brightness, backlight

Is there a way to adjust lighting step ? I have Lenovo L520, and Fn + Light Up or Down adjusts by 20%, how can I adjust the step to 10% ? it will help me fine tune lighting at my dark room.

Comment: @ఆగస్ట్ It's not a dupe of that one but [these](http://askubuntu.com/q/108065/12864) [two](http://askubuntu.com/q/180450/12864) are exact dupes, yet this one here is the oldest. The other two should be closed instead.

Comment: yup! you are right amigo . i will do the remaining job then :D

Comment: Given that most firmwares/OSs default to increments of 10%, your issue sounds like you just needed to apply the well-documented method of adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to your GRUB configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the percent of screen brightness that changes every time I press the shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48972/how-can-i-change-the-percent-of-screen-brightness-that-changes-every-time-i-pres)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Install xbacklight by opening a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut and type this:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then after installation, type these commands in terminal:

```
xbacklight = 10
xbacklight = 20
xbacklight = 5
```

this may help.

Comment: This method worked perfect for me! Other way is: xbacklight -dec 1, or xbacklight -inc 1 (to increase or decrease 1%)

Comment: On a Asus n55s `xbacklight` accepts any value (even with decimal places), but actual values (as visible by try and see, and as returned by `xbacklight` without argument) are rounded down to the nearest 10%.

Comment: It should be noted the `man` page recommends `-set` instead of `=`. More importantly, anyone mapping keys to this should really add `-time 0 -steps 1` - because otherwise, `xbacklight` applies backlight fading by default, which seems to really wind up your (at least my) CPU when 'scrolling' brightness by holding down the assigned hotkey. I'm talking all cores rising from 45 to 60 degrees, over just a few seconds - best avoided. To be fair, I'm using 1% increments - where fading is even more pointless than normal - but still, don't tax your CPU if you don't have to.

Comment: xbacklight doesn't work on asus x8ain

Comment: Lenovo Thinkpad T480s qith Xubuntu 18.04 gives `No outputs have backlight property`.

Answer (score 10):

There is a file in Ubuntu which stores numerical integer value of brightness.
you will find 3 files in the directory `/sys/class/backlight/<VGA>directory`
replace directory with intel_backlight for intel cards.

You will find the max brightness value in `max_brightness` file and according to that value set the brightness in `brightness` file.

Comment: This was shows if your hardware is capable for fine granularity or not.

Comment: using gedit, I notice 937 in the max_brightness file. What should I do? Decease it with a random number? @yask

Answer (score 8):

## For Xubuntu LTS

Firstly, install `xbacklight`

```
$ sudo apt install xbacklight
```

Secondly, check whether you have control over the backlight.

```
$ xbacklight -1
$ xbacklight +5
```

> Should these commands result in a **`No outputs have backlight property`** error, then [follow these remediating steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1114872/164341) before proceeding.

Once `xbacklight -1` and `xbacklight +1` work from the command line, proceed with assigning these commands to respectively the `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` keys. This is done by hitting those keys when asked by the Settings → Keyboard → Application Shortcuts application.

Finally, **reboot** for these changes to take effect.

[image: Keyboard settings]

Answer (score 4):

You can install [xcalib](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xcalib) and then type the command:

```
xcalib -co 50 -a
```

Use `xcalib -h` for help regarding it's options.

Comment: works on my macbook retina 15. Thanks! :-p

Comment: This works by sending darker images to your graphics card instead of adjusting the backlight. While it may seem to produce the desired effect, this is wasting energy and reduces the number of available colors.

Comment: @Sunday But we use it to protect our eyes, not the battery

Comment: I would not say that accidently reducing your color depth and thus introducing banding artifacts is very good for your eyes either...

Answer (score 3):

[As Colin Ian King said](https://askubuntu.com/a/170521/22949), the levels of brightness are hardware related.

Some laptop screens have 8 levels of brightness and new ones have 16 levels.

On Windows OSes you can change the levels with 1% steps, but they will be rounded to the nearest hardware level. It depends on the screen type.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 16.04, with Intel onchip graphics (i5) under LXQt, it is sufficient to assign [`xbacklight` commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/888135) to the brightness function keys `XF86MonBrightness(Down|Up)` using the global key shortcut settings. These seem to override the defaults even if `/sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled` [is set to `Y`](https://askubuntu.com/a/515420), while the original functionality on virtual terminals is retained.
[image: LXQt global key shortcut configuration with xbacklight commands]

An alternative to the original `xbacklight` would be [`acpilight`](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight), but unfortunately this isn't available as Ubuntu package. As it doesn't depend on an X display running, you can also associate it with ACPI button events and use it from the console. Additionally it can store the current brightness on shutdown and restore it on boot.

Comment: The same holds true for XFCE with Xubuntu LTS 18.04. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to install 'xbacklight'

Then I created keyboard shortcuts such as

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> with command `xbacklight +5`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> with command `xbacklight -5`

So when you use those shortcuts they call the related command 
however I could not replace the system inbuilt brightness buttons to use these commands
You can use almost any keyboard shortcut button combination you like with xbacklight.

Answer (score 2):

For me `xbacklight` did not work *(EDIT: probably because I did not reboot my machine)*, therefore I created my own script which uses the built-in `gsd-backlight-helper`.

This script uses smaller steps, especially when the screen is quite dark already.

**Step 0: check if it works (optional)**

To see if it works you could try:

```
pkexec /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --get-brightness
```

This should output a number.

**Step 1: save script**

Save the following script in an `.sh` file, for instance in `/home/me/scripts/brightness.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

max=$(pkexec /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --get-max-brightness)
cur=$(pkexec /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --get-brightness)
if [ $(($max/$cur)) -ge 25 ]
then
    step=$((max/300+1))
else if [ $(($max/$cur)) -ge 5 ]
    then
        step=$((max/50+1))
    else
        step=$((max/20+1))
    fi
fi
case "$1"
in
+) new=$((cur+step));;
-) new=$((cur-step));;
esac
pkexec /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-backlight-helper --set-brightness $new
```

**Step 2: assign shortcuts**

Open Keyboard Shortcuts from the Settings menu and assign shortcuts:

```
name:     Darker
command:  sh /home/me/scripts/brightness.sh -
shortcut: Super + F5

name:     Brighter
command:  sh /home/me/scripts/brightness.sh +
shortcut: Super + F6
```

Comment: what you mean ? xbacklight did not work ? when xbacklight is installed fresh, then you should reboot your machine. True, here was not said that, to reboot the machine.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I think I did not reboot my machine... Yet my script has the advantage that it uses smaller steps on darker screens and larger steps if the screen is quite bright already.

Answer (score 1):

The brightness levels are generally under ACPI control with the levels defined in firmware. For example the ACPI control method _BCL  "Query List of Brightness Control Levels Supported" informs the kernel how many brightness levels are supported.  You can't realistically change this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Lenovo T500) the problem is, that the brightness regulating key-press is applied twice - once by using the Xwindows, but also independently in the lower level, by kernel's graphic driver itself. So the brightness steps are twice as big as usual.

The working solution is to deny the low-level functionality, by adding this line to /etc/rc.local (just before the line with 'exit 0'):

```
echo -n 0 > /sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
```

This way it will perfectly work in logged-in X session, unfortunately it will remove the key-press brightness regulation functionality in all other cases (console terminal, X login screen etc).

Answer (score 1):

### Official documentation:

https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xbacklight.1.html

> `inc percent`
> Increases brightness by the specified amount.
>
> `dec percent`
> Decreases brightness by the specified amount.

Example:

`xbacklight -inc 10%`

`xbacklight -dec 10%`

Answer (score 0):

Brightness cannot controlled with large precision. I'm afraid that you're stuck with those brightness levels. To be sure, try controlling the brightness using [these terminal commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/48998/6969).

Comment: If I go to System Settings, I find an icon labeled 'Screen' If I click on that icon I get a scroll bar that can set the brightness in small percents, How can I get this screen icon to the top bar ( besides clock, or battery indicator ) ?

Comment: What about https://launchpad.net/indicator-brightness? I haven't tried it since I don't use Unity/GNOME.

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/58022/6969

Comment: It definetely can be controlled in smallest steps in many cases. Please have a look at http://askubuntu.com/a/205509/43165.

Comment: @vines Have you seen the linked post in my answer? It describes the same sysfs interface. The precision depends on the hardware. ACPI brightness values are often not that large. And the other driver interfaces it is possible that those use steps internaly (e.g. 1-10 still give "step 1").

Comment: @Lekensteyn All your points are absolutely valid. I'm just a bit more optimistic in saying that it can often be done, rather than it's completely impossible. :)

Comment: I like how this answer just fatalistically says there's no greater control than 20% available, without any reference to the OP's hardware, _then_ cites commands that for many people _do_ allow _much_ finer control. Handy!

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting it manually. First you have to get the PCI-ID of the VGA device:

```
lspci
```

Then try this (in my case the PCI-Device is 00:02.0)

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 f4.b=FF
```

The 2 letters at the end of the Line set the new brightness ranging from 00-FF (0-255)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Nvidia Graphic** card..you can easily use my new method of brightness changing,and edit values in Code.. theres two files and two options within each one.

find these two lines:

```
if ( $value > 0.0) { $value = $value - 0.30 };  
if ( $value2 > 1.1) { $value2 = $value2 - 0.08 };
```

change values of **($value > 0.0)** & **( $value2 > 1.1)** 
and see whats happens!

meanwhile if you dont want to change values and wish to use my method originally you can
change brightness in a wide range and 5 steps.
wish you like it

link of method: https://askubuntu.com/a/179063/82136

Comment: Uh... isn't this just mangling the bitmap before it's sent to the screen, rather than actually changing the screen's brightness?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on KDE, you can simply hover your cursor over the "Battery and Brightness" menu from your system tray and try to slowly scroll upwards or downwards to increment or decrement the brightness.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On modern Gnome environment you can achieve fine-control effect with mouse scroll:

If you have smooth-scroll touchpad, position mouse pointer over brightness slider from top-right menu and perform fine two-finger scroll to adjust brightness with tiniest steps.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while increasing/decreasing the brightness. Increases in steps of 1.