# How do you make the keyboard brightness button adjust at smaller intervals?

Tags: brightness, thinkpad, acpi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increase brightness in smaller steps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103249/how-to-increase-brightness-in-smaller-steps)

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad T60 running Oneiric. According to the files in /sys/class/backlight, I should be able to adjust the brightness level to a number between 0 and 7 (and I am able to do this successfully in terminal using

```
echo 4 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

). However, when using the keyboard button (Fn+Home, Fn+End), the brightness levels adjust by increments of three. For example, if the brightness is all the way up at 7 and I press the button once, it lowers to 4, then again to 1, then 0. I would like to change this so that it changes in increments of 1. E.g. It starts at 7, lowers to 6, then 5, and so on. Ideas?

Comment: I researched this awhile ago, but there seemed to be no easy solution. The reason, as I vaguely remember, it skips is that FN+* is getting sent twice for a hardware-related reason. Basically, the keyboard event is sent twice and the brightness always increments by 2 levels.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about those numbers, but on my HP laptop I used xbacklight to change my brightness. The brightness varies between 0 and 100 and pressing the brightness up/down keys changes the brightness by 10. I wanted something like five, so I mapped a key to the command

```
xbacklight -inc 5
```

and

```
xbacklight -dec 5
```

You might be able to use this as a workaround to your problem.

Comment: Anyone mapping keys to this should add `-time 0 -steps 1`. Otherwise, xbacklight applies fading by default - which seems to **really** wind up your (or at least my) CPU when 'scrolling' brightness by holding down the key. I'm talking all cores rising from 45 to 60 degrees, over just a few seconds - best avoided... To be fair, I'm using 1% increments - where fading is even more pointless than normal - but still, don't tax your CPU if you don't have to.