# Problem with brightness Sony Vaio NVIDIA graphics

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, brightness, shortcuts

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop (Sony Vaio VPCF22MOE).  My graphics card is NVIDIA GeForce GT 540M.

After ubuntu installation I installed NVIDIA Driver Version which is 295.33.  I uninstalled Nouveau using:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

I noticed a few things: my brightness <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are not working (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> / <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>f6</kbd>). Also in compiz 3D is not working. The brightness is set up to maximum.

I have tried almost everything. I have followed other threads and edited in million different ways `xorg.conf`. Xbacklight command in terminal doesn't work either. Does anybody have any idea how to configure it in order to make it to work?

---

Answer (score 1):

Im personally using Vaio VPCCW21FX (Nvidia Graphic) and Ubuntu Studio 11.10 ..
I tried many solutions and nothing could resolve my problem with LCD brightness!
Finally wrote these two perl files to manually set brightness/Contrast and Gamma functions inside Nvidia driver config file.

This will be helpfull only if you are able to change brightness within **Nvidia X Server Settings**

**Step 1:** create this file and name it "Brightness-Up.pl"
(you can use any text editing tool like : *gedit,nano,vi,etc..* copy & paste)

```
    ### Code by forgottenrip@yahoo.com ###
    my $find1 = "0/RedBrightness=";my $find2 = "0/RedGamma=";
open FILE, "<Nvidia-Settings.cfg";
my @lines = <FILE>;
for (@lines) {
    if ($_ =~ /$find1/) { chomp $_;$value= substr($_,16,5); }
    if ($_ =~ /$find2/) { chomp $_;$value2= substr($_,11,5);}     
}
my @Lines;
if ( $value > 0.0) { $value = $value - 0.30 };  
if ( $value2 > 1.1) { $value2 = $value2 - 0.08 };  
$last_value = $value + 0.30;
$Lines[0] ="0/RedBrightness=".$last_value;
$Lines[1] ="0/GreenBrightness=".$last_value;;
$Lines[2] ="0/BlueBrightness=".$last_value;;
$last_value = $value + 0.30;
$Lines[3] ="0/RedContrast=".$last_value;;
$Lines[4] ="0/GreenContrast=".$last_value;;
$Lines[5] ="0/BlueContrast=".$last_value;;
$last_value = $value2 + 0.08;
$Lines[6] ="0/RedGamma=".$last_value;;
$Lines[7] ="0/GreenGamma=".$last_value;;
$Lines[8] ="0/BlueGamma=".$last_value;;

$filename = "Nvidia-Settings.cfg";
open fh2,'>',$filename or die ("can't open '$filename': $! \n");
foreach ( @Lines )
{ chomp;print "$_\n";print fh2 "$_\n"; };
close fh2; 
`nvidia-settings -l --config=Nvidia-Settings.cfg`;
```

**Step 2:** then make another file, name it "Brightness-Down.pl" and fill with this code:

```
    ### Code by forgottenrip@yahoo.com ###
    my $find1 = "0/RedBrightness=";my $find2 = "0/RedGamma=";
open FILE, "<Nvidia-Settings.cfg";
my @lines = <FILE>;
for (@lines) {
    if ($_ =~ /$find1/) {chomp $_;$value= substr($_,16,5);}
    if ($_ =~ /$find2/) {chomp $_;$value2= substr($_,11,5);}     
}
my @Lines;
if ( $value < -0.80) { $value = $value + 0.30 };  
if ( $value2 < 0.8) { $value2 = $value2 + 0.08 };  
$last_value = $value - 0.30;
$Lines[0] ="0/RedBrightness=".$last_value;
$Lines[1] ="0/GreenBrightness=".$last_value;;
$Lines[2] ="0/BlueBrightness=".$last_value;;
$last_value = $value - 0.30;
$Lines[3] ="0/RedContrast=".$last_value;;
$Lines[4] ="0/GreenContrast=".$last_value;;
$Lines[5] ="0/BlueContrast=".$last_value;;
$last_value = $value2 - 0.08;
$Lines[6] ="0/RedGamma=".$last_value;;
$Lines[7] ="0/GreenGamma=".$last_value;;
$Lines[8] ="0/BlueGamma=".$last_value;;

$filename = "Nvidia-Settings.cfg";
open fh2,'>',$filename or die ("can't open '$filename': $! \n");
foreach ( @Lines )
{ chomp;print "$_\n";print fh2 "$_\n"; };
close fh2; 
`nvidia-settings -l --config=Nvidia-Settings.cfg`;
```

**Step 3:** You need to create another file which contains Nvidia Settings..
name it "Nvidia-Settings.cfg" its important that you write name exactly same. 
fill with:

```
0/RedBrightness=0.1
0/GreenBrightness=0.1
0/BlueBrightness=0.1
0/RedContrast=0.1
0/GreenContrast=0.1
0/BlueContrast=0.1
0/RedGamma=1.14
0/GreenGamma=1.14
0/BlueGamma=1.14
```

Thats it! now place these files in unique folder.. you have to bind your ***Function Keys*** to these two perl file.you can use **Compiz>commands** to do that.
Run below command to install the compizconfig-settings-manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

or even you can run seperately with these two commands in shell (terminal):

```
user$ perl Brightness/Brightness-Up.pl
user$ perl Brightness/Brightness-Down.pl
```

where Brightness is folder I put those files in it.

Comment: Uh... isn't this just mangling the bitmap before it's sent to the screen, rather than actually changing the screen's brightness?

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing: https://askubuntu.com/a/120796/54126
I had same problem with my nvidia 335m gt.
This trick made my backlight working with ability to change it via FN keys.

Also, if it affects, i have linux 3.2.0-20 kernel, and this thing is proven to work on 3.2.0-22 kernel also.
Give it a shot.