# xbacklight: No outputs have backlight property - No /sys/class/backlight folder

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, hp, backlight, xbacklight

I installed `xbacklight`, hoping that it would be able to control my brightness. When trying to change brightness, I was told "No outputs have backlight property". After looking around, I found that this has to do with my computer not having a `/sys/class/backlight` folder. I know that this is the problem but don't know exactly how to fix it.

Not sure if its needed or not but here some system info from inxi:

```
System:   Kernel: 3.16.0-57-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) 
          Desktop: LXDE (Openbox 3.5.2) Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:  HP EliteBook 8460p
CPU:      Dual core Intel Core i5-2520M CPU
Graphics: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
```

Does this have to do with drivers (perhaps Intel/AMD graphics drivers)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That is completely normal. To find the directory for your backlight settings, do this:

```
sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'
```

The output should give you something like this:

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Now, all you have to do is link it to `/sys/class/backlight`. To do that:

```
sudo ln -s /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/intel_backlight  /sys/class/backlight
```

If you still get the error, then do this:

Create the file `xorg.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

And add these lines:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier  "Card0"
Driver      "intel"
Option      "Backlight"  "NAME OF THE FOLDER"
EndSection
```

Then, to save the file do: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also, for the `Driver` part check for your configuration, i.e., `acpi_video0` or `intel_backlight`.

Comment: What if there is already a folder on that path? How do I undo such a replacing ln -s if it breaks brightness (by now it's at least controllable from keyboard)? I've tried creating `xorg.conf`, added both `intel_backlight` and the long absolute *path* to the folder. But it didn't work. So should I:  
1. Try ln -s cuz it's harmless 2. Try some other driver name (btw how do I know it otherwise part of the path?), or 3. Use not the path but the name of the folder (it would be same to `Driver` field so that's why I'm asking)?

Comment: In my computer if I open the file /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness, I will see an integer value inside it. Just changed the value and saved, my screen immediatelly got the correct brightness. But if I try to use the ln command proposed, I dont have exactly the same folder, and if I try to do this with my intel_backlight folder, I get the error: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/class/backlight/brightness': Operation not permitted

Comment: @user9589 This sounds like a permission issue. You did execute the ln command as root, didn't you? And I think you were supposed to link the folder, not the brightness file inside that folder. Anyway, the solution didn't work for me, but I already had a /sys/class/backlight folder.

Comment: For the `xorg.conf`, do I write the full path of the folder, or the name "intel_backlight"?

Comment: One reason for "operation not permitted" may be that the file name contains characters that should be escaped.  That was the case for me.

Comment: @YanKingYin How did you do that exactly?

Comment: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight 
the easyer way is just to tell the kernel that it is using the intel-backlight instead of whatever it is expecting

Comment: This did not find my backlight location. This did: `ll /sys/class/backlight/`

Comment: Is this file also correct, I assume I do not have `intel`: `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`. I also have a file `actual_brightness` in `acpi_video0`, both have a 0 integer as content.

Comment: Which one is it? There's so many in sys

Comment: Name of what folder?

Answer (score 49):

Check your `/sys/class/backlight` folder. If you can see an `intel_backlight` folder there and still you are getting the above error then creating a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file with the below configuration should work for you. It worked for me.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics" 
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

Also, remember to logout and login again for the changes to take effect.

Reference: [Backlight - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight)

Comment: This answer is the **most straightforward** for `intel_backlight` users.

Comment: logout and login didn't work for me, i had to reboot

Comment: Had to reboot too. This made `xbacklight` work but broke my brightness function keys in the process. For some reason xfce needed me to toggle a switch after that change: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight#Backlight_keys_not_working_in_Xfce

Comment: For some reason, this totally breaks hardware acceleration on a secondary monitor, had to revert

Comment: Shouldn't it be a file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` on `20.04`+? Tried putting it there and SDDM stopped starting :/

Answer (score 8):

## Every step required for `xbacklight` control

Follow these steps:

1. `$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and [replace the corresponding line with](https://askubuntu.com/a/426266/164341) `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
2. `$ sudo update-grub`
3. No joking, make sure that the [appropriate drivers are actually installed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851810#25): `$ sudo apt install xbacklight xorg xserver-xorg-video-intel`
4. Issuing `$ find /sys -type f -name brightness` should yield something like `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness`
5. `$ cd /sys/class` This directory should contain a soft link called `brightness` to the brightness device discovered in the previous step. Should it be missing, create it: `$ sudo ln -s /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness /sys/class/brightness`
6. `$ sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf` should read:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Device0"
    Driver          "intel"
    Option          "Backlight"      "intel_backlight"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen0"
    Monitor         "Monitor0"
    Device          "Device0"
EndSection
```

7. The assignment of the physical `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` keys is [explained here for Xubuntu LTS or XFCE users](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080149/164341).
8. Finally, **reboot** for these changes to take effect.

Comment: For step 5 I keep getting `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/class/brightness': Operation not permitted`

Comment: did you add sudo? and you can check if the dir exsists

Answer (score 6):

I woudn't recommend that way as it starts the old bad maintained Intel driver instead of the modesetting driver.

I created a script instead of using xbacklight:

```
#!/bin/sh
val=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)
if [ "$1" = "+" ] ; then
  val=`expr $val + 5`
else
  val=`expr $val - 5`
fi
echo $val | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

and added tee to sudoers. That works without side effects caused by the Intel driver.

Comment: does it harm, or have any side effects to run
sudo chmod a+rwx /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

and use your script with 'tee' instead of 'sudo tee'

Comment: @mbkfa93 how to make this persistent across reboot ?

Comment: With some mods, turned out to be my solution in the end. I don't see the need in some specialised HW handling programs if all we need is this nice sysfs interface. My version of the control changes it by logarithmic scale, i.e. multiplying / dividing by a factor (with couple of edge cases) - this is more natural to human's perception of what "equal changes must look like".

Comment: @gruvw: The recipe for persistence is listed on the same acpilight's page from another answer, works for me after changing the permitted group to 'users' (default user group in my system):
""
To do so, place a file in /etc/udev/rules.d/90-backlight.rules containing:

SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", ACTION=="add", \
  RUN+="/bin/chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness", \
  RUN+="/bin/chmod g+w /sys/class/backlight/%k/brightness"
""

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control external monitor, then a way using xbacklight does not work.

You can use xrandr instead of using it.

E.g.:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 0.5
```

(You can get monitor name like 'HDMI1' by `xrandr --listmonitors`.)

[ref:archlinux bbs.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=197583)

Comment: Do note this doesn't actually change the brightness of your monitor's backlight. As per xrandrs man page: 
"Multiply  the gamma values on the crtc currently attached to the output to specified floating value. Useful for overly
              bright or overly dim outputs.  However, this is a software only modification, if your hardware has support to actually
              change the brightness, you will probably prefer to use xbacklight."

Answer (score 0):

I am an Arch Linux user and I encoutered same problem.
I can't link driver to `/sys/class/backlight` because `/sys/class/backlight` existed as a directory and I can't replace it.

After some research I found [Yuri D'Elia / acpilight · GitLab](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight).
I installed acpilight with pacman and problem solved.

Now I can change brightness of screen with `xbacklight +5`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, modifying the kernel parameter `acpi_backlight` to `native` worked:

```
cat /boot/loader/entries/arch.conf

- options root=UUID=... acpi_backlight=vendor rw
+ options root=UUID=... acpi_backlight=native rw
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).