# Xbacklight won't help to change brightness in lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, intel-graphics, brightness, xbacklight

I have an old acer laptop with following graphics hardware:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: 
Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller [8086:8108] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0244]
```

I used xbacklight's `xbacklight -set XX` and `xbacklight -dec XX` commands but they don't work. If I put these commands, the output is

> No outputs have backlight property

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xbacklight: No outputs have backlight property - No /sys/class/backlight folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder)

Answer (score 2):

You should set the brightness from `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file, see my answer in: [i3wm, adjust brightness through command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843103/i3wm-adjust-brightness-through-command-line)