# i3wm, adjust brightness through command line

Tags: unity, xbacklight

I've got a Precision 5510 running Ubuntu 16.10 with kernel 4.8.4. In unity, my function keys for brightness work correctly. But xbacklight commands don't do anything. xbacklight -get comes up empty. Is there a way to increase / decrease brightness through the command line? I need this for it to work in i3wm.

Comment: Apparently a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xbacklight/+bug/1638136

Answer (score 5):

You may modify the value in /sys/class/backlight/{may vary}_backlight/brightness

example:

```
sudo nano /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

This tool does that https://github.com/multiplexd/brightlight
then use it like this:

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec --no-startup-id brightlight -i 20
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec --no-startup-id brightlight -d 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to "brightlight" :) had some issues with "xbacklight" but brightlight works beautifully (y)! Bound it to my keywoard keys in i3 using `brightlight -p -i 10` and `brightlight -p -d 10`

Comment: Thank you! Been dealing with blinding 100% brightness for over 5 years! Mine was at `/sys/class/backlight/psb-bl/brightness` for anyone reading this with a Sony Vaio P series.  I tried the boot flag and xbackglight without avail, but changing the file worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I am using now i3wm with Ubuntu and i love it. I have a similar problem and i solved this adding this lines in my `~/.config/i3/config` file:

```
# Sreen brightness controls
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec echo $((`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` + 10)) | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec echo $((`cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` - 10)) | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightnes
```

and add the `/etc/suduers.d/tee` file with this:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/tee
```

where `myuser` is really my user name. My laptop is an HP Spectre x360 with Intel graphics, I know that i need to check the min and max limits but at least in my machine ... no problems ...

Comment: This seems like a huge security vulnerability. Doesn’t this allow any process to edit any file on the system without requiring a password?

Comment: @Steve looks very dangerous