# Brightness control in SwayWM (i3wm wayland)

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, i3-wm

So, I have the laptop without buttons on the keyboard for brightness control and when I try to change my config then these shortcuts are not working. Any ideas? `# Sreen brightness controls`
`bindsym $mod+i exec xbacklight -inc 20 # increase screen brightness`
`bindsym $mod+o exec xbacklight -dec 20 # decrease screen brightness`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the xbacklight commands on their own?
If they don't work you could try using this tool https://github.com/multiplexd/brightlight then:

```
bindsym $mod+i exec --no-startup-id brightlight -i 20
bindsym $mod+o exec --no-startup-id brightlight -d 20
```

Refer to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/878962/41785

Comment: So, it works nut only in Terminal with SUDO command, how can I use it without SUDO? Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu ships with brightnessctl

Add yourself to the video user group with `sudo usermod -aG video ${USER}` to be able to use it without superuser privileges.

To add to the other answer, this would be

```
bindsym $mod+i exec --no-startup-id brightnessctl s 5%+
bindsym $mod+o exec --no-startup-id brightnessctl s 5%-
```

https://github.com/Hummer12007/brightnessctl/issues/63