# xbacklight produces "no outputs have backlight property", and brightness buttons dont work

Tags: keyboard, xorg, brightness, asus, backlight

I use an Asus E202S notebook.

I can't change my brightness using <kbd>Fn</kbd> key combinations.

When I use `xbacklight`, it returns

```
no outputs have backlight properties
```

In my `/sys/class/backlight` directory I have two symbolic links:

```
asus-nb-wmi
intel-backlight
```

I tried some suggestion with `xrandr` and changing pci but to no avail.

I have created an `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11`:

```
Section "Device" 
Identifier "Card0" 
Driver  "intel" 
Option  "Backlight"  "intel_backlight" 
EndSection
```

Yet still no change.

I am a complete newbie, so please help accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xbacklight: No outputs have backlight property - No /sys/class/backlight folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem so I made this script.

clone this repo and paste the script into the `/bin` directory. then make the script executable by using the following script.

`sudo chmod +x /bin/backlight.sh`

here is the repository for the script:

`git clone https://github.com/el-beth/backlight.sh.git`

in your case, change the third line of the script from:

```
BRIGHTNESS_DIRECTORY=$(cd /sys/class/backlight/* && pwd);
```

to

```
BRIGHTNESS_DIRECTORY=$(cd /sys/class/backlight/intel-backlight && pwd);
```

for more info read the README.md file in the cloned `backlight.sh` directory.

Comment: the third line is not BRIGHTNESS_DIRECTORY=$(cd /sys/class/backlight/* && pwd); i found it to be 
MAX_BRIGHTNESS=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/*/max_brightness);