# How to have xbacklight working in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: bug-reporting, xbacklight

xbacklight worked perfectly in Kubuntu 14.04 but now in Kubuntu 16.04, even when it it installed, I only get this message:

**No outputs have backlight property**

In my system there is a /sys/class/backlight folder already, so please note that this is **not** a duplicate of the completely different question in [xbacklight: No outputs have backlight property - No /sys/class/backlight folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder) where the OP very clearly states in the title I **do have a /sys/class/backlight folder, so this is not the same case, please read the title of that question where it says explicitly "no /sys/class/backlight folder"**

Comment: it's a bug in KDE. You can write directly to the file to change brightnes, but keyboard controls and brightness slider have no effect

Comment: @ravery Nope. I can control the screen brightness with the function keys perfectly. But not from shell scrips or the konsole using xbacklight.

Comment: Hmm, different but possible related. In my case KDE was looking for video_bl0 (or something like that) when I have radeon_bl0. Perhaps yo have a similar issue. My backlight works perfectly with Mate desktop.