# Can't modify files in a directory even with root

Tags: permissions, sudo

While following this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/715310

I ran the command:

```
sudo ln -s /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/amdgpu_bl0/brightness /sys/class/backlight
```

and I got the error:

`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/class/backlight/brightness': Operation not permitted`

Other commands like `mkdir` and `touch` return the same error: `Operation not permitted`

I have tried running `chown -R root /sys/class/backlight` and running all the commands threw `root` but that didn't help either.

How come `sudo` cannot perform this operation and how can I fix it?

Comment: That directory is not *actually* a directory you can create new links in - that directory isn't a 'normal' directory location.  Why're you trying to create such a link?

Comment: I am just following the instructions in: https://askubuntu.com/a/715310

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files inside of `/sys` and `/proc` are *virtual* file systems like `procfs` where the files aren't real.

> The proc filesystem (procfs) is a special filesystem in Unix-like operating systems that presents information about processes and other system information in a hierarchical file-like structure, providing a more convenient and standardized method for dynamically accessing process data held in the kernel than traditional tracing methods or direct access to kernel memory.

More info see [proc on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs)

Also see [man procfs](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/procfs.5.html)

Comment: So if you can't create links in /sys how come the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/715310/909484 got accepted?

Comment: I believe the reason is that you can *write* and modify some contents of the pseudo-file system, but you cannot create new files within it, since they have nowhere to go. In this case it seems like you are trying to create a new file instead of symlinking to an existing file. Eg. try symlinking the amdgpu_bl0 directory not the specific brightness "file"