# How do I change the screen brightness in Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, brightness, xbacklight

I bought a new laptop and installed Ubuntu but I'm unable to change the brightness through settings and the keyboard. I also tried installing brightness controller but it has no effect either. I installed `xbacklight` and followed the solution given here [xbacklight: No outputs have backlight property - No /sys/class/backlight folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder).

When I type `sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*'` my output is:

```
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/virtual/leds/hp::hddprotect/brightness
/sys/devices/virtual/leds/hp::hddprotect/max_brightness
/sys/module/video/parameters/hw_changes_brightness
/sys/module/video/parameters/brightness_switch_enabled
```

I'm using an AMD Ryzen 3 processor.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: What is the laptop make and model?

Comment: @Pilot6  Ubuntu version is  Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix laptop is a  HP probook 445 g7 r3

Comment: @RizanaFazily You could ask in HP forums like this person did: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/Brightness-keys-not-working-in-Linux/td-p/7549927

Answer (score 0):

The two last lines (`/sys/video`) seems more relevqnt than the rest.
Have you seen the answer on [That post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303429/acpi-video0-brightness-no-effect-on-the-screen)? using `xrandr` to find your target screen then `xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness .4` to set the brightness. is that working for you?

Comment: That solution is software controlled brightness for external monitors. The question is about hardware brightness for laptop display.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the 5.8 kernel that supports brightness control for new AMD GPUs by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

reboot after it is installed. The brightness should work.

Comment: I did this but after the reboot my laptop screen is blank...i cant do anything please help

Comment: Toy can always boot woth a previous kernel using grub menu.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Press ESC on boot and select advanced options.