# No way of changing the screen brightness in Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS on a acer TravelMate

Tags: 20.04, screen, brightness, backlight, ubuntu-studio

I am working on a Acer Travelmate 5360G with dual boot, Lubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu Studio 20.04. In 18.04 I could not change brightness with `Fn + ArrowLeft` and `Fn + ArrowRight`, but I made a little python script which writes the value directly to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` and bound that to `Alt + ArrowRight / ArrowLeft`, which works perfectly fine.

I then tried doing the same on Ubuntu Studio 20.04, but it doesn't work there because `/sys/class/backlight` is just empty (gives `file or directory not found`) !
The weirdest thing on this is, that the first time I booted into 20.04, my script worked ***perfectly*** fine !? But the next time I booted, I got a grey screen forever. The solution for that was to add `nomodeset` to the grub options for 20.04. But after that, my brightness script stopped working !

I tried installing the proprietary drivers in `software-properties-gtk`, adding `acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux` to grub's boot options, I tried changing the brightness with `brightness-controller`, `brightnessctl`, `xrandr`, `xbacklight`, ***none*** of these did have ***any*** effect. If you need anymore details, please simply let me know - honestly, if you don't know a solution now, I'll just give up on Ubuntu Studio :( !

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder/1060843#1060843)?

Comment: @PedroMaimere no, will try tomorrow and let you know if it helped !

Comment: @PedroMaimere I did exactly what was described in the post you linked; neither that nor installing the proprietary drivers through `software-properties-gtk` helped - anymore ideas ?

Comment: @PedroMaimere finally fixed - see my post how ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got my Fn brightness keys working ! Here is how:

1. Reboot
2. Go into BIOS by holding down F2
3. Go to Main tab
4. Change `Graphic Mode` from `Switchable` to `Discrete`
5. Save changes and exit
6. Continue boot
7. et voila !

But … my screen resolution had become low, and everything looked as if someone had trod on it … somewhat squashed …

I was able to fix that, too:

1. Open `/etc/default/grub` with root privileges in your favorite text editor
2. Change `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x360` to `GRUB_GFXMODE=1360x768` (my screen resolution is 1360x768)
3. Run `sudo update-grub`

Additionally, I ran `sudo prime-select intel` - I do not know how much that helped.
After that, it finally worked.

And, after 1 to 3 reboots (I dont know how much exactly), I finally even got the folders in `/sys/class/backlight` back ! :)