# Smaller brightness interval when adjusting with hotkeys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, laptop, lenovo, brightness, backlight

In Ubuntu 16.04 on my Lenovo ideapad 510s, I can use F11/F12 to get 22 different levels of brightness from virtually blank (1) to max (535), but from manually setting the level in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` I know my hardware supports far more than that. When I use the hotkeys, `brightness` changes by a somewhat arbitrary 26 either way. Is there a way I can change that interval of 26 to something more like 5 or 10?

The suggestions I have found so far involve adding `acpi_backlight=vendor` to `default/grub`, which completely disables my adjustments, or installing xbacklight, which was unresponsive and would just be a workaround at best. [The first answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150166/change-the-brightness-adjustment-interval) is close to what I was looking for, but it's specific to KDE.