# How do I change the amount by which the brightness increases or decreases?

Tags: brightness

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increase brightness in smaller steps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103249/how-to-increase-brightness-in-smaller-steps)

When I press Fn + F6, the brightness increases. Lets say the brightness increases by 1 unit. How do I make it increase by 0.5 units? I hope you understand my question. I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. If thats important.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xbacklight` you can increase or decrease your brightness by whatever percent you prefer.

```
xbacklight -set 1
```

or `xbacklight -set 0.5`
it accepts integer of even fractions.

Comment: My question is how do I change the amount by which it increases when I use the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Its manufacturer defined, you can't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is only possible to increase and decrease it by a sections like from 1 to 3 any nothing in between can be selected, otherwise you should get software that you can get a slider so you can manually slide the brightness according to your preferences.

Better explained, using the sound as an example. By using the shortcut on you keyboard, the sound can also just increase and decrease by amounts that is default by the key, when you use the slider of the window of the computer, then you can manually change it to 0.5 or 0.8 just as you would like it.

Hope you understand, so look for something that can bring up a slider for the brightness - there should be software on the internet....

Comment: there is no need for software for the slider. It is available by default in Ubuntu.