# Brightness adjust Ubuntu vs Xubuntu

Tags: 14.04, brightness

I have little problem: LiveCD with ubuntu 14.04 can adjust brigthness on laptop and with xubuntu 14.04(installed from mini.iso)

What package i need to install for brightness adjustment.

- OS (x)Ubuntu 14.04
- Laptop: Toshiba TecraA11-182

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood why brightness adjust haven't worked.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

...doesn't install package `xfce4-power-manager`. So installing this package helped me to solve this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-power-manager xfce4-power-manager-data xfce4-power-manager-plugins
```

Next reboot your laptop and enjoy it.

Comment: Same for me on 18.04. Works great simply after installing power manager.

Answer (score 0):

## Setting up `xbacklight` control

Follow these steps:

1. `$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and [replace the corresponding line with](https://askubuntu.com/a/426266/164341) `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
2. `$ sudo update-grub`
3. No joking, make sure that the [appropriate drivers are actually installed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=851810#25): `$ sudo apt install xbacklight xorg xserver-xorg-video-intel`
4. Issuing `$ find /sys -type f -name brightness` should yield something like `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness`
5. `$ cd /sys/class` This directory should contain a soft link called `brightness` to the brightness device discovered in the previous step. Should it be missing, create it: `$ sudo ln -s /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness /sys/class/brightness`
6. `$ sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf` should read:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Device0"
    Driver          "intel"
    Option          "Backlight"      "intel_backlight"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "Screen0"
    Monitor         "Monitor0"
    Device          "Device0"
EndSection
```

7. The assignment of the physical `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` keys is [explained here for Xubuntu LTS or XFCE users](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080149/164341).
8. Finally, **reboot** for these changes to take effect.

Comment: Please read my own answer. 
I have installed my system from mini.iso. As next step i installed `xubuntu-desktop` meta package, which hast took `xfce4-power-manager` package. This package makes whole magic for user.