# Brightness issue on xUbuntu

Tags: brightness

The brightness on my laptop shortcuts can be increased/decreased my a margin of 10%(which is the default). The issue is that when I have it on 10% it's still too bright for me. How do I change the margin at which it changes to 5% instead of 10%?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase brightness in smaller steps?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103249/how-to-increase-brightness-in-smaller-steps)

Answer (score 0):

You could also set it through software.
I am not familiar with how to do it on xUbuntu but Kubuntu has the Power and Brightness options right by the notifications.

There are also applications which offer even more control like [Brightness Controller](https://github.com/apandada1/Brightness), which you can install after adding the repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller
sudo apt update
sudo apt install brightness-controller
```

You can also try using xrandr with this option shown in `man xrandr`

```
       --brightness brightness
          Multiply  the  gamma  values on the crtc currently attached to the output to specified floating value. Useful for overly bright or overly dim outputs.  However, this is a software only modification, if your hardware has support to
          actually change the brightness, you will probably prefer to use xbacklight.
```