# How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?

Tags: command-line, brightness, backlight

To work around [bug #1005495](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1005495) (changing LCD brightness via hotkeys impossible), I'd like to have one command line query for increasing and one for reducing the brightness of my LCD. I could then map a hotkey to each one of this queries.

The problem is: I don't know how to increase and reduce the LCD brightness on the command line. Do you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to change brightness in a Lenovo laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57236/unable-to-change-brightness-in-a-lenovo-laptop)

Comment: Thanks, Lekensteyn, but it's not a duplicate since  lsmod | grep ^i915 gives me no output (see accepted solution). Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 189):

Open your terminal and type this

```
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
```

it will gives you the output as

> ```
> LVDS1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
> ```

There LVDS1 Stands for your display. So now you have to do as

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.5
```

there 0.5 stands for brightness level and it ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 .
0.0 -> Full black .so you have to choose the required value of brightness .

This **doesn't change brightness at a hardware level**. From [`randr` manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr):

> `--brightness brightness` Multiply the [gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) values on the crtc currently attached to the output to specified floating value. Useful for overly bright or overly dim outputs. However, **this is a software only modification**, if your hardware has support to actually change the brightness, you will probably prefer to use xbacklight.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but what I'd need is something like xrandr --increase 10 to increase the brightness by 10 percent. Is that possible, too?

Comment: @user69748 well, you could use my first answer for that purpose .

Comment: thanks but that doesn't work for me as written there.

Comment: this doesn't seem to change the brightness at a hardware level

Comment: Elaborate the issue please

Comment: In my case, the `xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.2` approach works fine while `xbacklight -set 20` fails. And I have the same question as @user69748: is it possible to use `xrandr` to change brightness by +/-0.05?

Comment: @landroni lemme look

Comment: @landroni xbacklight not having full support for some hardware.

Comment: Ah, OK, thanks! So there is no way to  +/-0.05 brightness for `xrandr` users?

Comment: Regarding user84207'c comment, then I fear the same: It seems that at 0.0, the screen is all black, but still lit up, making it seems that the screen lights are still firing away, wasting battery. So is the brightness just changed on the graphical level, comparable to changing the brightness of a photo or in a game?

Comment: Too bad this answer got so many votes. My laptop screen "emulates" darkness so to say by making things appear darker (just as when you play a video with a night scene, that has nothing to do with the screen lightness but rather with pixels masking the background light). The lightness is exactly the same, wasting even more battery than before because of the pixels than now are darker.

Comment: @Mephisto All Laptops are not same. All answers are not same.

Comment: @Raja I have a question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/664693/is-there-an-app-that-can-make-my-desktop-dimmer) that I think could use your input, Thanks

Comment: It fakes the brightness. The brightness does not change, it is rendered by software.

Comment: @user1970939 I will try to update my answer. But please remember this answer was posted 4 years ago.

Comment: I can confirm that this only emulates the brightness and does not change the brightness of the display's background light. Interestingly, the brightness of the mouse pointer is not changed, leaving it much brighter than the rest of the desktop.

Comment: Just what i needed `xrandr --output LVDS-1 --brightness 0.08` for night

Comment: @Neil did you mean `0.8` rather than `0.08`?

Comment: In one line: `xrandr --output $(xrandr -q | grep " connected" | col1 | tail -1) --brightness 0.9`

Comment: "it ranges from 0.0 to 1.0 . 0.0 " is not true. 20.04 I can change it to 1.1

Comment: Exactly, this does not change the brightness on the hardware level just like I can change it using the keyboard keys. xbacklight doesn't work for me either because I have Radeon GPU.

Answer (score 167):

The following works for me:

```
echo 400 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

I guess the maximum possible value is in the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` file.

Replace `intel_backlight` with an asterisk to apply to all backlights.

Comment: This is useful information but it doesn't work for me. Permission denied, even if I `sudo`. I also tried to `vim` the file and edit it, but it won't let me, saying something like "Fsync failed".

Comment: @Ray Try this: `echo 400 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`.

Comment: Oh wow it works! I'm not really Linux-savvy so as far as I'm concerned right now this is magic.

Comment: @Ray when you do `sudo echo 400 > /sys/class . .. ./brightness` redirection is done by shell , not by echo. And shell still runs as your regular user, not as sudo. That's why it gives permission denied.  You need to have a utility that will write to file with root permissions, which is why `tee` works.

Comment: `echo 400 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness` for radeon APUs and cards

Comment: This is ridiculously low-level, but in fact seems to be the only thing that reliably works. It gets a bit less ugly if you `sudo chmod 0646` the `brightness` file, so `sudo` isn't needed for setting brightness anymore.

Comment: The reason that this is set at su permissions is that a virus could conceivably make your screen dim and go bright at incredible speed ultimately damaging your hardware display. In the 90's I encountered a virus that would adjust the screen refresh Hertz so rapidly that your monitor would fry. So be careful tweaking the permissions on this.

Comment: echo '30000' | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/gmux_backlight/brightness for me

Comment: Instead of changing the permissions of the file, you can add a script to the sudoers as a NOPASSWD entry (and change the script's permissions to require root to edit it). From there you can implement timeouts and any other protections you see fit.  Alternatively you could write a daemon to periodically copy the brightness setting from a writable local brightness file to the live one. Either method means you can bind keys to modify the brightness without entering a password or leaving the master unsecured.

Comment: RyanNerd , really because monitors anyways change the brightness really quickly to make it dimmer or brighter using PWM. Also lightboost does change it really quickly too so i think that it does no damage

Comment: I do `sudo nano /sys/ ... /brightness` then I can change the value and apply it with `Ctrl O`. On my system, if I set it to anything above 976 I get an "invalid argument" error. This seems to be the max brightness here.

Comment: for me this worked well as `su` (not `sudo`)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. With Ubuntu Server, or any headless system, you don't want to install an window manager just to get access to `xrandr` or have `xbacklight` work. This works perfectly on my MacBook Air running Ubuntu Server 19.04 without any extra packages required.

Comment: `sudo bash -c "echo 400 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"` to give permission to bash managing redirection to file.

Comment: …bypainstakingly narrowing down the interval I 'learned' that 4437 is the highest brightness level on my lenovo laptop. (4438 will get you an 'invalied argument'

Comment: Thanks, +1. This works on Wayland too. The screen on my Dell Latitude 5590 didn't respond to any other control, and was nearly unreadable, at a value of 375 out of a maximum of 7500.

Answer (score 163):

**Note**: `xbacklight` only works with Intel, not properly on Radeon and not at all with modesetting driver ([source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#xbacklight)). It also only works on X11, not Wayland.

---

One more way we have to do this  is with another new program named as xbacklight , open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then type this `xbacklight -set 50`

there 50 stands for brightness range we can get it upto 100 from 0 .

you can also increase and decrease the brightness from present value to specified level.as you mentioned if you want to increase to 10% from current value of brightness then you can give this

```
xbacklight -inc 10
```

and to decrease 10% you can give this

```
xbacklight -dec 10
```

Comment: Looks like a really simple command but what I'd need is something like xbacklight -increase 10 to increase the brightness by 10 percent. Is that possible, too?

Comment: @user69748 answer edited

Comment: Yes you can. I've already mention that . so you can get that by xbacklight -inc 10

Comment: That really looks simple, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work for me. Brightness simply doesn't change, not with -dec and not with -set. I guess I'll have to hope the bug gets fixed any time soon. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: This works better than the `xrandr` thing on my Ubuntu 14.04 Lenovo laptop. setting the brightness via `xrandr` changes a different brightness setting, but xbacklight seems to change the same setting that the keyboard brightness buttons change

Comment: It is very simple and thanks for that. It is working for me(Ubuntu 14.04, HP DV6), But it does not increase by the amount of 10%. I have used custom shortcut for the increase and decrease command, but they reach the 100 in just 4 clicks. and difference between the 3rd and 4rth times key press, there is more difference in the brightness compared to 1st, 2nd, 3rd key presses(when i start from lowest brightness). Can anybody tell me the reason behind it or point towards right direction.

Comment: Why is this answer not the accepted answer ? I have just tested on LTS 14.04 and it works like a charm. I like very much xbacklight -dec 1 to decrease from 1 unit until get get what you need. You get also get the current value. -get.

Comment: Additionally, there's a shorthand you can use:

`xbacklight +10; 
xbacklight -10; 
xbacklight =50;`

Comment: worked great for me on 16.04.1-gnome. also hooked the +10/-10 up to my keyboard shortcuts that were previously not working using the gnome Keyboard app.

Comment: My `lubuntu 16.4.` does not work with the `--inc`. I have two aliases: `alias x+='xbacklight -set 40'` (which is quite light) and
`alias x-='xbacklight -dec 10'`

Comment: I have Radeon GPU and Intel processor. xbacklight has no effect on the brightness.

Answer (score 24):

### Using D-Bus with GNOME

You can increase/decrease brightness [with `gdbus`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/gdbus.1.html):

```sh
# Step up
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp

# Step down
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown
```

#### Notes

- **No root privileges needed!** Unlike the [`/sys/class/backlight` way](https://askubuntu.com/a/469040/349837).
- Source: [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Backlight#Using_DBus_with_GNOME) ([here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/keyboard_backlight#On_GNOME) for keyboards).
- `xbacklight` [not always work](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#xbacklight).
- [`xrandr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xrandr) (from x11-xserver-utils) just does a [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction).
- [Probably works on MATE and Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus#GDBus). For KDE check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/439293/349837), using [`qdbus`](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_Connect/Tutorials/Useful_commands#Brightness_settings).
- [`ddcutil`](https://www.ddcutil.com/) might work on external monitors with [DDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel#DDC.2FCI) support

Comment: +1 confirms this works great on internal LCD display. It doesn't effect external monitors already controlled with `xrandr` gamma and brightness scripts.

Comment: This proved to be very practical and worked well with different hardware. Thanks.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to set absolute values (like 100% brightness) using this way?

Comment: nothing changed but got this output: `(0, 'eDP-1')`

Answer (score 13):

For Laptops,

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80
```

Change `80` by `[0-FF]` to get lowest-highest brightness.
The value specified is in hex, so `80` will give you a `50%` of max brightness.

For Desktops to make a [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction) (not tested by me),

```
xgamma -gamma .75
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but what I'd need is something like setpci --increase 10 to increase the brightness by 10 percent. Is that possible, too?

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me on a Samsung NB30 Plus.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.. Should I change some parameters, perhaps, and if so, how do I find the appropriate values?

Comment: Thanks I'm on a laptop, `setpci` didn't work but `xgamma` did.

Comment: If you want to use a [0-255] range you can use `$(echo "obase=16; ibase=10; 128" | bc)` (for ~50%). The `ibase=10;` is optional.

Answer (score 5):

Make this script:

`set-brightness.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
TARGET="acpi_video0"
cd /sys/class/backlight
MAX="$(cat "${TARGET}/max_brightness")"
# The `/1` at the end forced bc to cast the result 
# to an integer, even if $1 is a float (which it 
# should be)
LOGIC="$(echo "($1 * ${MAX})/1" | bc)"
for i in */; do
    if [[ "${TARGET}/" != "$i" && -e "${i}brightness" ]]; then
        cat "${i}max_brightness" > "${i}brightness"
    fi
done
echo "$LOGIC" > "${TARGET}/brightness"
```

Run it as root, with any value between 0 and 1.

```
sudo ./set-brightness.sh 0.5
```

- If your system doesn't have an `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0`, there should be at least one directory in there, which may be device-specific (I also have a `radeon_bl0`, for example).
- If you have others, keep in mind their values stack (hence the loop; pushing all the *other* values to 1.0, then setting the target one to the desired amount).
- While `acpi_video0` *should* always work, it doesn't always have the full range of physical brightnesses available.  Try each one, and use the one with the largest gamut as your "TARGET"

Comment: Consider using `/sys/class/backlight/*/brightness` instead of trying to hard-code `acpi_video0` into the script. It will allow for generalizing the path to file, which can be different - i for example have `intel_backlight`, not `acpi_video0`. That's what I've used in my [script here](http://askubuntu.com/a/743141/295286)

Answer (score 4):

#### KDE 4.12:

```
qdbus org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement /org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/Actions/BrightnessControl setBrightness 55
```

#### KDE Plasma Version: 5.14.3:

The above code is still valid. It will only work if you are a KDE user. However in that case it will require no additional piece of software. It will have the exact same behavior as when using the "battery and brightness" widget. AFAIK it changes the physical backlight, in contrast with `xrandr` which does does not.

Beware that the 55 above is not a fraction of 100, the latter being the max brightness.
Instead it is related to max_brightness:

```
qdbus org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement /org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/Actions/BrightnessControl brightnessMax
```

There is also a "silent" version that you might prefer in a script:

```
qdbus org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement /org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement/Actions/BrightnessControl setBrightnessSilent 2000
```

Refs: [qdbus](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/D-Bus/Introduction), [solid](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Solid/Introduction), [brightness](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight)

Comment: can you explain what It will do ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this in terminal:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.9
```

You can change the last value as you like, eg. 0.2

Comment: 1) Output is not always LVDS1, but user can find out with xrandr --verbose
2) Doesn't change backlight intensity

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short line that can help you relax your eyes. Just create a crontaab with the line or make a script

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 0.5; sleep 20; xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 1
```

Answer (score 3):

As @palacsint said, `echo 244 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` path works for me.

But max and min values are resent in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` and `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power` files respectively.

Also, the actual brightness that your computer is running now is present in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness`

Answer (score 3):

[ddccontrol](https://github.com/ddccontrol/ddccontrol/) is another option for controlling backlighting for external monitors. Here I can set the backlight of my external monitor to 50% of its power with:

```
ddccontrol -p -r 0x10 -w 50
```

I looked in possible solutions for this problem to improve the way [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) handles [brightness changes](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/436). Through there I found that there is a [patchset for the Linux kernel](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9530565/) to improve compatibility across devices, so that laptops and external screens could work similarly, through `sysfs`.

In the meantime, ddccontrol is the only thing that works for me here. As usual, the Arch wiki has [good overall documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight) on the topic as well.

Answer (score 3):

To set absolute brightness (for laptop users):

```
BRIGHTNESS=50 # 0 to 100

dbus-send \
--session \
--type=method_call \
--dest="org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power" \
/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power \
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set \
string:"org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen" \
string:"Brightness" \
variant:int32:$BRIGHTNESS
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the above answers, I created this script (saved in my home directory as `brightness.sh`) to modify display brightness (as the laptop's keyboard suffered a spilled tea issue and became unusable).  Feel free to use it (if you have the designated files... otherwise tinkering to point to your variation of them will be necessary).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
function main_menu {
  sudo clear

  cursetting=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness)
  maxsetting=$(cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness)
  powersave=$((maxsetting/5))
  conservative=$((powersave*2))
  medium=$((powersave*3))
  performance=$((powersave*4))

  echo ""
  echo "----------------------- Brightness -----------------------"
  echo " 1. Set Display to Minimum (Powersave) brightness setting."
  echo " 2. Set Display to Low (Conservative) brightness setting."
  echo " 3. Set Display to Medium brightness setting."
  echo " 4. Set Display to High (Performance) brightness setting."
  echo " 5. Set Display to Maximum brightness setting."
  echo " 6. Exit."
  echo "----------------------------------------------------------"

  if [ $cursetting -eq $powersave ]; then
    cursetting='Minimum'
  else
    if [ $cursetting -eq $conservative ]; then
      cursetting='Conservative'
    else
      if [ $cursetting -eq $medium ]; then
        cursetting='Medium'
      else
        if [ $cursetting -eq $performance ]; then
          cursetting='Performance'
        else
          if [ $cursetting -eq $maxsetting ]; then
            cursetting='Maximum'
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi

  echo "        Current Display Setting - "$cursetting;
  choice=7
  echo ""
  echo -e "Please enter your choice: \c"
}

function press_enter {
  echo ""
  echo -n "Press Enter to continue."
  read
  main_menu
}

main_menu
while [ $choice -eq 7 ]; do
  read choice
  
  if [ $choice -eq 1 ]; then
    echo $powersave | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
    main_menu
  else
    if [ $choice -eq 2 ]; then
      echo $conservative | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
      main_menu
    else
      if [ $choice -eq 3 ]; then
        echo $medium | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
        main_menu
      else
        if [ $choice -eq 4 ]; then
          echo $performance | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
          main_menu
        else
          if [ $choice -eq 5 ]; then
            echo $maxsetting | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
            main_menu
          else
            if [ $choice -eq 6 ]; then
              exit;
            else
              echo -e "Please enter the NUMBER of your choice: \c"
              choice = 7
            fi
          fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi
done
```

Comment: You could do better than just nesting a lot of if conditions, like `elif` or even better `case`. Also I suggest reading a style guide like https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml and trying a linter like shellcheck as it helps you create better code. I wish someone told me this when I started scripting years ago. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am using i3 as my window manager and I had uninstalled gnome, so the gnome solution didn't work for me. And the other software based approaches just made the screen look more black.
So, after a bit of reading, I came across [brightctl](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/brightnessctl.1.html).
Install it using apt install.

```
sudo apt install brightctl
```

You will need permissions to modify the display device, which only members of the group ***video***(and obviously root) can do. So, make sure you add the current user to the ***video*** group. You can do this like so :

```
sudo usermod $(whoami) -a -G video
```

After installation, I can increase/decrease brightness using the below commands by 10 -- this is very gradual and gives me more control. :

```
#Increase brightness
/usr/bin/brightnessctl -d intel_backlight set +10

#Reduce brightness
/usr/bin/brightnessctl -d intel_backlight set 10-
```

I have added keybindings in my i3 config. Here is a snippet of the keybinding.

```
#Increase brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec  /usr/bin/brightnessctl -d intel_backlight set +10

#Reduce brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec /usr/bin/brightnessctl -d intel_backlight set 10-
```

Comment: In current Ubuntu, the package is called `brightnessctl` - like the command

Answer (score 2):

To increase brightness using xdotool, run the following command:

```
$ xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessUp
```

To decrease brightness using xdotool, run the following command:

```
$ xdotool key XF86MonBrightnessDown
```

Since xdotool simulates real hardware keypresses, this is a hardware level change of brightness.

Source: https://linuxhint.com/display_brightness_commandline/

Comment: This is great. My laptop screen brightness has gone below 5% so I went to another monitor in run in terminal a couple of times.

Answer (score 1):

**Interactive ncurses-like UI using `xbacklight`**

A poor man's ncurses. Hit `h` and it goes down 10%, hit `l` and it goes up 10%. Then show the current luminosity.

```
xback() (
  done=false;
  echo "less: h, more: l, quit: q"
  while ! $done; do
    read -rsn1 key
    if [ "$key" = h ]; then
      xbacklight -dec 10
    elif [ "$key" = l ]; then
      xbacklight -inc 10
    elif [ "$key" = q ]; then
      done=true
    fi
    printf "\r$(xbacklight -get) "
  done
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [placsint's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/469040/67745)

```
cd /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/
cat max_brightness | sudo tee brightness
```

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/469040

Answer (score 0):

You can set the x% brightness of display on follow way:

Syntax:

```
sudo brightnessctl -d intel_backlight set [your wanted value in % of max]
```

Install brightctl:

```
sudo apt install brightctl
```

Set the brightness to one % value in a range of 0 - 100 %:

```
sudo brightnessctl -d intel_backlight set 60%
```