# How to prevent Ubuntu from changing screen brightness?

Tags: brightness

I have recently installed 12.04 on ASUS-K53SV-V300. I can change the brightness on start-up with:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness >> /etc/rc.local
```

or manually by <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

But, whenever Ubuntu dim my screen brightness to save power or wake-up from suspend or inactive for 20-30 seconds, brightness reset to high (my problem get much more when on battery).

How can I disable screen brightness service to prevent it from changing my brightness? What service work on screen brightness? If I disable this service, can I manually set brightness by command?

find a replacement to work on brightness instead of default power manager.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script/149265#149265

Answer (score 5):

You can turn off brightness adjustments to save power in `System Settings->Brightness and Lock`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't want your screen to turn off or dim at all, I recommend the tool Caffeine.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install caffeine
```

If you turn on Caffeine, it will prevent your screen from dimming and switching of. That tool always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the core codes of the tool caffeine which written by Python mentioned above and I found the command

```
$ xset -dpms; xset s off
```

seems useful.