# Brightness control works only in Ubuntu, doesn't in Xubuntu/Lubuntu/Kubuntu/Mint (Toshiba Satellite L30)

Tags: xubuntu, brightness, toshiba

All tested OS were in latest versions (12.04.1 and Mint 13 Mate&XFCE).

Already tried xfce panel aplet for screen brightness, `acpi_backlight=vendor` argument in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and replacing xfce-power-manager with gnome-power-manager.
Default keyboard shortcut for brightness control should be Fn+F6/F7. 
Shortcuts for mute, volume up, down and for disable/enable wifi are working properly.
For now, I'm able to control brightness only by terminal `echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`.

Just checked Debian Wheezy with Gnome 3 - also works, but I really want to install Xubuntu on this machine.

Comment: Did you try this solution ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script/149265#149265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem, i unchecked "Power Manager" from "Application Autostart" list in `Settings -> Session and Startup` and added another application with this command `xfce4-power-manager --no-daemon` then i have not have this problem yet.