# Fn key combination *suddenly* stopped working for brightness only

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, laptop, brightness

I've looked at most of the questions relating to enabling hardware brightness control under Ubuntu with the Acer Aspire S3 laptop; initially these fixes worked, under the initially installed kernel 3.2.0-57-generic.

I installed 3.8.0-34-generic to enable Bluetooth, and everything seemed to work fine after a couple of restarts, but today I booted it up and the brightness adjustment was not working. Specifically, the brightness meter does not even appear. All the other fn combinations work (excepting the sleep shortcut), including the combination to disable the backlight.

I applied the fix to `/etc/default/grub`, namely

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

which had originally given me control of brightness, but now has no effect. I also experimented with adding and removing `pcie_aspm=force, i915.i915_enable_rc6=1, i915.semaphores=1` to that line, but there was no change in behavior.

I also tried adding a keyboard shortcut for XF86MonBrightnessUp/Down but the key combination Fn+RightArrow/LeftArrow seems to be getting caught by the system before it reaches the keyboard shortcut config program.

How do I debug this and get brightness working? (I don't want to reinstall and repeat.)

edit: I also tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181350/brightness-control-works-only-in-ubuntu-doesnt-in-xubuntu-lubuntu-kubuntu-mint) to no avail.

Comment: how did you install the different linux kernel? can you confirm using `uname -a` that it is still being used?

Comment: I installed it through aptitude, through the package `linux-signed-generic-lts-raring`. `uname -r` returns `3.8.0-34-generic`.