# Unable to adjust brightness in Ubuntu/Xubuntu/Lubuntu13.04

Tags: xubuntu, 13.04, brightness, asus

I've recently upgraded to Xubuntu 13.04 and noticed that I'm unable to use the brightness keys to adjust the brightness of my screen. I've tried just about everything [this thread suggest](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139397&p=12621502&viewfull=1#post12621502) and I'm still unable to find a solution. If it helps at all I'm using an ASUS eeepc 1025c.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you change the brightness in the brightness & lock section of the settings?

Comment: Does xbacklight work under any conditions? If you try to alter your brightness while `xev` is open dose any new text appear in the terminal and if so what?

Comment: Hey @GM-Script-Writer-62850 I see this when I try to adjust my screens brightness with xev open: 

FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

Comment: That means it is possible for the system to capture your brightness keys and run a command when you press them, now if you get find a grub boot parameter(s) that lets `xbacklight` work, you can add a keyboard shortcut for `xbacklight -inc` and `xbacklight -dec` the shortcut being your brightness keys

Answer (score 1):

You can changing the brightness using the command line on this thread. It's not a perfect solution but it will allow you to give you control in adjusting. You can always write a bash script afterwards.

Source:
[How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)