# Setting which brightness determines screen brightness

Tags: kubuntu, laptop, screen, brightness

I'm having an issue running Kubuntu 13.04 with brightness, something that seems common. In particular, brightness can be found in these 2 directories:

```
/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Now, the Fn+Up/Down buttons do in fact edit the brightness as specified in acpi_video0: however, this brightness is not what is rendered, instead the intel_backlight brightness is rendered and that one I have to edit it manually.

How can I set it so that the brightness specified in acpi_video0 is the one that my laptop renders, so that I can use the button shortcuts to change brightness as desired?

Answer (score 1):

Then you can use Xbacklight command , It going to use the ACPI modules to control the system brightness with some commands.

[How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script/149265#149265)

If you dont want to do that way , Then Edit the shortcut key which was assigned to 
 `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` to `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

so everytime you call the hotkey instead of intel , acpi will have the call.

I mean simple change the way.