# no display backlight after boot on my notebook

Tags: boot, display, backlight

i insttalled ubuntu 13.10 on my COMPAQ PRESARIO CQ-41 209TU notebook.but whenever it comes on login screen, display backlight turns to 0.why?please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem on a laptop (different type) too. It is usually related the video driver.

As a woraround, I used xbacklight (see [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)) to change the display brightness, and put a call to a script with that command to lighdm startup code (/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, either display-setup-script, session-setup-script, or both).