# Making screen brightness change smoother

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, acpi

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS on Lenovo G580. The Function key is working fine for brightness change, but I want to make the change smoother, i.e. reduce the step change in brightness per key press. Any Ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can also increase and decrease the brightness from present value to specified level.as you mentioned if you want to increase to 10% from current value of brightness then you can give this
>
> ```
> xbacklight -inc 10
> ```
>
> and to decrease 10% you can give this
>
> ```
> xbacklight -dec 10
> ```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/149265/186134)

Maybe you want to change the 10 to 5 or even 3, to have a slower transition, so use

```
xbacklight -inc 5
```

and

```
xbacklight -dec 5
```

---

To reassign the keyboard short cuts - using the GUI - follow this:

Open system settings, and click keyboard.

[image]

Click Shortcuts, then custom shortcuts.

[image]

Click `[+]` then type the following (ignore what I put in the image):

> Brightness Up
>
> ```
>  xbacklight -inc 5
> ```

[image]

Click disabled and press your chosen shortcut key:

[image]

And repeat for the brightness down.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It worked like a charm. Although "xbacklight" is not installed by default so one has to install it first.