# How can I change the screen brightness on Zenbook UX305 with media-buttons?

Tags: shortcut-keys, laptop, asus

The  keys <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> do not change the brightness on my Asus Zenbook UX305.
I can change the brightness from the command line with this command:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness 0.5
```

This example reduces the brightness to 50% of the rather bright default on the UX305.

**But how can I use the default keys (see above) to change the brightness?**

---

<sub>**Warning**: Do not use a brightness value greater than 1.0. Damage to your screen or eyes may result.</sub>

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX305, UX303UA, ...
Ubuntu: 14.04, 16.04

Related: [How to Enable Brightness Buttons in 16.04 of Zenbook?](https://askubuntu.com/q/816264/25388)

Comment: If Fn-keys are not supported we can do that from command line. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script (can also be assigned to a custom key shortcut)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/816264/25388

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same problem with the newer UX305CA. Apparently it is really common [since the hardware is not recognized](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1348890), so I just assigned a new shortcut. Following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/149265/47254):

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Then assign new shortcut:

- <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> > <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> > <kbd>Custom Shortcuts</kbd> > <kbd>+</kbd>

Add those two:

- Brightness up: `xbacklight -inc 10`
- Brightness down: `xbacklight -dec 10`

Then click on each of the `Disabled` and select the new shortcut. In my case I used Alt+F5 and Alt+F6 (since I use Ctrl+F5 for web dev).

If you want, you can also [mess with the boot options](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1348890/comments/10) to fix it:

> Hi,
>
> I have the same problem. there is a workaround although.
>
> add "acpi_osi=" at the and of the kernel boot parameters.
>
> to permanently do this edit /etc/default/grub as root and add "acpi_osi=" at the end of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT then run "update-grub" as root
>
> after that brightness and all other hotkeys work but the ambient light sensor is no longer detected. But this is not a big problem since there is no standard ambient light regulation of screen brightness anyway

Comment: Zen UX305UA / 16.04 LTS: xbacklight works, but brightness keys(FN + F5/F6) are not recognized. `acpi_osi` detects keys correctly, but has no effect (brightness doesn't change at all, neither through hotkeys, brightness app nor xbacklight)

Comment: Have you tried to use the `modesetting` package? Please, see http://askubuntu.com/q/816264/25388

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested by auto brightness for this notebook (through ALS sensor) it can help to you:
https://github.com/Perlover/Asus-Zenbook-Ambient-Light-Sensor-Controller/tree/asus-ux305
It works at my Asus UX305 ;-)
But you need to blacklist acpi_als module before

Comment: Is there anything related in apt-get? It would be great to understand this part also better.