# Issues in saving screen brightness

Tags: 14.04, brightness, hp-pavilion

I have Ubuntu 14.04LTS and a HP Pavilion dv6500. My computer doesn't remember the amount of brightness everytime I turn it on.
Can somebody help me with some terminal command lines?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this command:

```bash
echo 2500 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

More info, please look in this thread [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script/149265#149265)

Answer (score 0):

I use xbacklight to do this, which is simple and works perfectly.

Install it via terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

Then, I have a command set to run on startup:

```
xbacklight -set 0
```

(replacing 0 with whatever brightness level you'd like, 0 to 100)

Hope this helps!