# The brightness 'function' buttons do not work on Asus X200LA (Core i3 - 4010U) running Ubuntu MATE 16.04

Tags: 16.04, brightness, asus, mate

Looked for the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762764/cant-change-brightness-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts), one pointed to a software which shifts colour of the display but doesn't change the brightness.

Help, please?

Comment: [here's](http://askubuntu.com/questions/798203/changing-screen-brightness-through-keyboard-functions-on-my-notebook/798537#798537) my workaround for the Asus X205TA