# Screen brightness malfunction after I put computer to sleep "suspend"

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, screen, brightness

I have Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on a MacBook Air 11" 2014. The screen brightness buttons work flawlessly at boot, however if I suspend the computer and wake it up again anything bellow 80% brightness makes the screen so dark that there is no backlight at all and anything above 80% brightness sets the display at full brightness.

Comment: Sound like a bug to me. Weird indeed.

Comment: Is there a solution or a workaround though ?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/149264/308164), or the others in the post. Just type in after restoring session.

Comment: thank you @luchonacho, I tried that from what I now understand is that I can change my brightness with xrandr however if I use my power manager  or xbacklight all brightness levels bellow 80% are 0% and all above 80% are 100%

I am currently working on a bash script that will allow me to change my brightness with hotkeys using xrandr. I will be posting it here when it is done

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually apple specific and is a known issue with Ubuntu on Macbooks.

[Here is a resource on how to solve most of the problems with running Ubuntu on a macbook](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Trusty)

A workaround for the backlight problem is also there:

> [Look at comment 78 of this bug
>   report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67454#c78)
>
> Patrik Jakobsson wrote a [kernel
>   module](https://github.com/patjak/mba6x_bl) that directly programs the
>   backlight driver and it works!
>
> If you don't want to compile by yourself, follow these steps.
>
> 1. Install Build-Essentials and headers
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
>    ```
> 2. Download [mba6xbl-dkms_0.0.3_all.deb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Trusty?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mba6xbl-dkms_0.0.3_all.deb) and install it with
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg -i mba6xbl-dkms_0.0.3_all.deb Note: Repeat this installation step each time you kernel gets updated.
>    ```
> 3. Load the module:
>
>    ```
>    sudo modprobe mba6x_bl
>    ```
> 4. Log out and log back in. It should load automatically on next boot

I do not recommend downloading the (mba6xbl-dkms_0.0.3_all.deb) because it personally did not work for me, try a newer version:
[mba6xbl-dkms_1.0.0_all.deb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir6-2/Wily?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mba6xbl-dkms_1.0.0_all.deb)