# Adjust brightness of a MSI laptop in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, brightness, msi

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 for the first time a week ago. I can't adjust the brightness of my laptop, and my eyes often shed tears after using it for one or two hours. Can anyone give me some advice about how to adjust the brightness?

Laptop info:

[image: laptop info]

Comment: Here, this should help:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241724/which-command-can-i-run-to-adjust-brightness-of-my-screen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)