# Which command can I run to adjust brightness of my screen?

Tags: brightness

My LUbuntu 18.04's lxpanel is not working. Which command can I run to   adjust brightness of my screen? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, run `xrandr | grep " connected" | cut -f1 -d " "` to get your screen name.
Once you got your screen name, run `xrandr --output <screen_name> --brightness <brightness_value>`, the brightness value is between 0 and 1.

**CREDIT:** [How To Control Your Monitor Brightness From Command Line In Ubuntu?](http://sandipbgt.com/2015/10/01/control-screen-brightness-from-commandline-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: A good answer, this did the trick for me.