# Screen brightness not changing Ubuntu 16.04 Dell Inspiron N7010

Tags: 16.04, dell, laptop, brightness

In the system settings for ubuntu 16.04 I can't change the screen brightness on my Dell Inspiron N7010, the scroll bar moves but nothing actually changes.  Additionally I can't change the brightness through the terminal through any commands I have found on google.  Can anyone help me or provide suggestion?  It drains my battery extremely fast to have it on 100% brightness all the time.  Thank you!

EDIT:

$ head /sys/class/backlight/*/*brightness*

```
==> /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/actual_brightness <==
6

==> /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/brightness <==
6

==> /sys/class/backlight/dell_backlight/max_brightness <==
15

==> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/actual_brightness <==
617

==> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness <==
617

==> /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness <==
4882
```

$ lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Dell Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: Identify your graphics card

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please provide us some information of your computer such as your graphics card information. Also for the battery, install `tlp` package for battery optimization.

Comment: Can you add the output of `head /sys/class/backlight/*/*brightness*` to your question please, additional to some information about your graphics hardware and driver, e.g. the output of `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'`?

Comment: @ByteCommander
I added the graphics card information and the output of the backlight brightness.

Comment: The graphics card is Intel Ironlake Mobile. Same issue here.

Comment: I see.  Ya I am not sure what happened.  I think it has something to do with the original operating system on the laptop...    I think it has windows 7 home premium from factory?  Not sure but after the ubuntu installation this feature broke for me and every solution I tried did nothing.  I ended up reinstalling windows 7 ultimate I think on it to try and remedy the problem.  Still nothing.  Now just have to deal with a super bright screen, an extra laptop battery from the drainage rate, and an adapter replacement every couple months cuz the one for this lappy sucks.

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't work under Windows either. Yes, it originally had Win 7. Thanks for the response. If I ever find a solution I'l come back here with the answer. I didn't think it would be a big deal but it really hurts my eyes at night. It didn't work on 10.04 either http://www.linlap.com/dell_inspiron_17r

Comment: I understand.  Best of luck!  I would help the search but I haven't used that laptop in a while, been doing most of my development work on my PC with ubuntu 18.04.  Thank you

Comment: Thanks to you too! I've settled on this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/469040/39783
It's terminal based but seems to work on a hardware level rather than some of the colour related tricks that exist.

Comment: Looks good :)  Thanks I will have to give it a shot one of these days.

Answer (score 0):

I used the terminal commands listed both in & below the following YouTube video, to successfully control the brightness in Ubuntu MATE 16.04, on a Lenovo G570 laptop:

"Brightness Indicator : Easily control screen brightness in Linux Mint (Ubuntu)"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5_HyOT519U

You can simply copy/paste them from below the video (running them one after the other), into your terminal window.

Alternatively, have you simply tried the FN key + Down Arrow ?

Comment: I followed the instructions in the YouTube video, to no avail.  The brightness indicator is installed, though when I changed the value associated with it, the screen brightness does not actually change.  Additionally, FN key + Down Arrow doesn't respond as expected.