# Disable screen on lid close but don’t sleep

Tags: lid, systemd-logind

In Ubuntu 18.04 server I want to be able to shut the lid of my laptop and have the following happen:

- The screen turns off.
- The laptop itself keeps running and does not go to sleep.

If I set this in /etc/systemd/logind.conf

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

It achieves the second goal, but not the first (the screen stays on). Setting “lock” instead of “ignore” didn’t help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years later, I have an answer for this.

Firstly, you want to do what I mention in the original post to make closing the lid not make the laptop sleep:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Secondly, you want to turn your screen off by putting something like this in your crontab (`sudo crontab -e`):

```
@reboot echo 0 | tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

This command turns the screen brightness to zero. `@reboot` means it'll run on system startup.

If this command doesn't work for you, try another of the commands in [this stackoverflow answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script).