# Brightness key not working Acer ASPIRE v15

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, laptop, brightness, backlight

The brightness key (<kbd>Fn + left/right arrows</kbd>) on my Acer ASPIRE v15 laptop> on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS are not working.
I can control the brightness by changing the value of brightness by editing the file: `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

I want to connect the (<kbd>Fn + arrow</kbd>) key to a script which edits the value in the
above file. But `acpi_listen` does not detect the pressing of (fn +  arrow(left or right)) key. Though, it is able to detect (fn + arrow(up or down)) keys for volume control.

**How to get these keys detected for brightness control by the acpi?**

**Edit**: Binding another keys(other than the (fn + arrow) and calling the script as non-acpi event forces me to run the script  by placing it inside `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory in order to avoid prompting for password at each press of the key. (as changing the value of brightness requires root permission).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You haven't told us your release of Ubuntu, or your desktop (which may be the default, but without release we cannot know).

Comment: I am using Ubuntu  16.04 LTS .

Comment: [You don't need root privileges](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107046/349837) to change brightness

Answer (score 0):

At first we need some information about the video card. Just to make sure the right one is working. For example it is a APU (CPU+GPU in one processor). Intel or AMD does not matter. In my example it is an i5 470U processor. For further use we need the ID of the graphic card:

```
$ sudo lspci | grep VGA

--> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor 
    Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
The ID is 0:2:0
```

For further information about the vide device use

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
```

We need to edit/create a config file for xorg:

/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf

For our example the following section has to be inserted:

```
Section "Device"
      Identifier "Intel Graphics"
      Driver "intel"
      Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
      BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
      EndSection
Section "Device"
```

Source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/Intel/

Then the grub bootloader has to be edited to rewrite the list of supported OS.
This Bios option was introduced during the time of windows vista.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Bootoptionen/

Grub editieren and extend the following line with acpi_osi=Linux in

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Close file and update grub

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Reboot the System.

```
$ reboot
```

The keys (with the sun symbol) on your keyboard for regulating the brightness should work now.

Comment: (Thank you for the contributor who also made some correction of my post)

Comment: tested with Ubuntu 20.04 lts und 16.04 lts.

Answer (score -1):

In settings > Devices > Keyboards look for the hotkeys for controlling brightness. If your built in keys don't work, you can manually bind over them (Select the adjust brightness shortcut and press `Fn` + `L/R`)

Comment: I am unable to bind fn  + l/r key through this method.

Comment: It seems that acer doesnot support fully featured acpi for GNU/Linux. I am just going with running the script and linking to other keyboard short cuts.