# Brightness Control Doesn't Work

Tags: nvidia, brightness

I'm using a Lenovo Flex 15 with Ubuntu 18.04, and even when I move the brightness slider in the settings the brightness doesn't change. The Fn buttons don't work either. I tried the `acpi_backlight=vendor` thing, and it still doesn't work. I use an NVIDIA GeForce MX230 graphics card. Even if there's a way to just force brightness change using the terminal, I would be open to any suggestions.

EDIT: Even brightness control has no effects. When I change the brightness using any method, my screen's actual brightness level stays the same even though the settings stay otherwise. And now the brightness slider has completely disappeared

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to map the missing keys using `xkeyboard-config`. I recently created a keyboard map for the Microsoft Surface keyboard and it was pretty straight forward. Most modern keyboard configurations are derivatives of the evdev standardized keyboard layout and simply override incorrectly assigned keycodes and/or provide missing assignments. I found [this guide](https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450) to be quite helpful in creating my own mapping.

Have you tried manipulating the brightness controls by manipulating `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0` (or similar) or via DBus? See [this related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script) for how to use those two methods. If you're able to change the values with either of those methods then you should be able to map your brightness control keys to the appropriate `XF86MonBrightnessUp/XF86MonBrightnessDown` commands. You can also try using `xbindkeys` to send the appropriate commands.