# Increased brightness on every startup

Tags: 20.04, laptop, intel-graphics, screen, brightness

I like to keep the brightness to minimum always because my laptop is already pretty bright even in the lowest brightness. Every time I turn on my Ubuntu laptop the brightness is little higher than zero. I have to manually turn down the brightness to the lowest myself after it starts up on every single system startup.

Edit: The latptop I'm using Dell Vostro-15-3568. It has Intel Graphics. All the information can be acquired by Googling its name. If there is some specific information you need, the please ask me.

If you're running Ubuntu on a laptop, can you test it yourself by decreasing the brightness to minimum and then restart to check if it's still at minimum or if it's been increased after the boot?

Comment: Provide full details on your system and graphical card. One can change brightness with a command that depends on the system. Once you know the command to set it, you can have it executed automatically after login or even earlier in the boot process.

Comment: Does this help?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/

Comment: @vanadium Which details exactly should I post? Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2) Laptop: Dell Vostro-15-3568. Brightness can be adjusted using the brightness key, I'd rather prefer it to change manually like I do on every boot instead of setting up a permanent cmd for it. Does Ubuntu normally show this behaviour where the brightness is slightly higher than normal?

Comment: Include all relevant details in your question. Behaviour depends on computer type, graphics card and driver used. For me, the brightness is correctly remembered between boots, but that is not always the case.