# Set custom shortcut keys for brightness on iMac 2011 Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness, mac

It works on the slider and it previously worked on a keyboard that had brightness keys. My new keyboard does not have dedicated keys. So I want to add a keybind in settings -> keyboard shortcuts -> add custom shortcut.

What is the command for it though?
xbacklight -10
and
xbacklight +10
does not work... any other ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming you're using Gnome (the default desktop environment), have you tried the two commands in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1107046)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Harry! These two commands worked :)

## Step up:

gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepUp

## Step down:

gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.StepDown