# Ubuntu 22.04 - Display is dimmed after waking up from sleep

Tags: display, 22.04

Just upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 (too bad it had to go thru 21.10 and then to 22.04), but after upgrade was completed, after it goes to sleep (close the lid or just inactivity), it wakes up dimmed.

When pressing the bar properties (top right, by the battery sign ), the display brightness slide is in the same place it was left (quite close to 100%), when actual display is about 60-70%. When touching its slider, it goes back to its expected value.

I'm using an i7 ThinkPad.

Appreciate any help

Guy

Answer (score 1):

If you can find a terminal command or script that reliably changes your screen's brightness in hardware, you should be able to make your system automatically change its brightness back to 100% after every wakeup. Here's a really long list of techniques for changing screen brightness from the command line: [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)

Once you find the command that works for you, turn it into a script like this (adapted from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404010):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $1 in
  post)
    plop your screen brightness fixing command here
  ;;
esac
```

Obviously, replace the placeholder accordingly. Then save the script as `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/brightnessfix.sh` (assuming you don't already have a script named `brightnessfix.sh` in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep` directory), and then run the following sequence of commands to set the permissions properly:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/brightnessfix.sh
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/brightnessfix.sh
```