# sudo error, is mode 0777, should be 0440

Tags: sudo

I am getting sudo errors, how do I fix this error?

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0777, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Comment: As users before have noted, using "chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers" when the sudoers.d/README file has the wrong chmod DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: Are you suggesting that when the problem is the permissions on `/etc/sudoers.d/README`, that the error can still say `sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0777, should be 0440`?

Answer (score 26):

### First Option

Following [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=2280159&postcount=14):

1. Reboot PC
2. When the GRUB boot selection screen shows, choose Recovery Mode. (If it doesn't come up, press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the GRUB loader down the bottom).
3. A black terminal should come up, at this point you can run this command (you should have root privileges):

   ```
   chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
   ```

### Alternatively

You will have to put Ubuntu onto a LiveCD, boot into the LiveCD, mount your Ubuntu Partition on the Hard Drive (Open a file browser, like Nautilus, and click your Ubuntu Partition; or click Places->"xxGB Partition/Your Ubuntu Partition").

Then, open a terminal within the LiveCD session and type these two commands:

```
cd /media/<name of permanent ubuntu partition>/etc
sudo chmod 0440 sudoers
```

### Extra Problems

If there are any errors (as posted below), follow the error prompt and adjust each file accordingly using one of the above two steps:

> sudo apt-get update sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is mode 0777, should be 0440 sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700 [sudo] password for

Fix by following through with:

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/README
chmod 0700 /var/lib/sudo
```

Both of these commands should be used appropriately with the outlined steps above. They will change the file permissions associated with that file. 0440 will give the owner (root) and the group [read permissions](http://catcode.com/teachmod/numeric.html) and 0700 will give the owner (root), read, write and execute permissions.

Comment: I can use the sudo command but limited.                                                                                                                         `sudo apt-get update
                sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is mode 0777, should be 0440
  sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for`

Comment: @Alex: ESC is for GRUB legacy right? Shift should be pressed for GRUB2.

Comment: @user20698: you do not need `sudo` for the first, the second should be done from a Live CD.

Comment: If sudoers is 0777 shouldn't user be able to run `chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers` without sudo as sudoers is writable by everybody?

Comment: @Seppo: no, only the owner of a file can change file permissions.

Comment: Well, the issue is still here. `sudo apt-get update
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d/README is mode 0777, should be 0440
sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for`

Comment: @Lekensteyn Haha, cheers mate, I'm still living in the simple days of Legacy, changed as per your advice :P

Comment: @Seppo As Lekensteyn stated, not if you don't own the file. For example: `sudo -i` `touch /home/<user>/test` `chmod 0777 test` `logout` `chmod 0440 test`

Comment: @user20698 Wow, you really gave a workaround to your sudo base; for each error, you'll have to do the same steps as above, I've added in examples, also, can you post the output of `ls -al /etc/sudoers.d/` so we can get an idea of what else you've modified? Cheers

Answer (score 16):

[`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) is broken in this situation, but [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) (the command-line frontend to [PolicyKit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html)) still works, so you can fix it with a single command. No rebooting is necessary.

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

This assumes PolicyKit is installed. If this is a desktop system (rather than a server with no GUI), it is.

Answer (score 4):

Boot into recovery mode, choose the root shell, and:

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

Or if you don't want to restart you can use this alternative:

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

it will change the permission. Try it it will work.

Comment: Why are you `chmod`ing some files to `440` and others to `0440`? Shouldn't you use `0440` uniformly? And why are you changing permissions on `/etc/sudoers.d/README` when you use the `pkexec` way, but not otherwise? And what about other possible files in `/etc/sudoers.d`?

Answer (score 1):

What did you do to get these errors?

- If you did: `sudo chmod -R 777 /etc`, you need a Live CD to repair this.

  1. Boot into a Live CD and select "Try it"
  2. Mount your Ubuntu partition (or the partition containing `/etc` if you've put `/etc` on a separate partition). This can be done by using a file browser like Nautilus or the *Places* menu
  3. [Open a Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/38162/6969) by going to *Applications* => *Accessories* => *Terminal*
  4. Determine the folder of you Ubuntu partition, you can list the contents of mounted partitions by using `ls -l /media`. It's possibly named `ubuntu` or `disk`. In the next steps, I'll assume `ubuntu`.
  5. In the Terminal, set restrictive permissions by default:

     ```
     sudo find /media/ubuntu/etc -type f -exec chmod g-wx,o-rwx {} \;
     sudo find /media/ubuntu/etc -type d -exec chmod g-w,o-rwx {} \;
     ```
  6. Next, use the Live CD as reference point for restoring file permissions. The below command will change the file permissions for `/etc/media/ubuntu` using the `/etc` folder on the Live CD as reference point. It'll only change permissions on files (`-type f`) and directories (`-type d`) on the same filesystem (`-xdev`). Any errors are written to `~/errors.log` Errors like "file not found" indicates that a file on the system is installed, but not found on the Live CD. The command from step 5 should set the right permissions for it, but for the best results, you'd better reinstall the packages.

     ```
     cd /media/ubuntu && sudo find etc -xdev \( -type f -o -type d \) -f -exec chmod --reference=/{} {} \; 2>~/errors.log
     ```
  7. Now safe `~/errors.log` somewhere (like http://paste.ubuntu.com/) so you can add it as comment to this answer should you've any problems with applications.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu you can first strike <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> which opens the terminal. 
After that you can copy-paste the command below with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste in terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

```
pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to add one more step the the `pkexec` suggestions, per [this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/18012#issuecomment-335350903), I was lucky that I happened to have 2 ssh sessions going when I made the stupid mistake:

1. Open 2 terminals
2. In terminal 2, run `echo $$` to get PID
3. Run `pkttyagent --process PID_FROM_STEP2` in terminal 2
4. In terminal 1, run `pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`
5. In my case, I also had to run `pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers`